# Bookmarks have evolved into Saves

Tags: discussion, profile-page, bookmarks, announcements, saves

#### Update Oct 6

Maintenance is complete: all bookmarks have been migrated to Saves across all network sites, including Stack Overflow. All saves, saved lists, private notes, and bookmarks are now available in Saves.

#### Update #2 Oct 5

Site is stable again.

Saves is enabled again for all users network wide. Your saves, saved lists, private notes, and migrated bookmarks should be available to you now. Bookmarks that were made during the outage period will be unavailable until we finish migrating tonight.

All bookmarks should migrate tonight. Until then, sites are either fully migrated or not migrated. The only exception is Stack Overflow which is still partially migrated with 360k of 14mil bookmarks migrated.

We have a maintenance window planned starting at **00:00 UTC**. If all goes as expected, it should be done by **02:00 UTC**.

#### Update Oct 5

Saves has been temporarily disabled network-wide due to some site performance problems. These problems didn't appear until partway through migrating existing bookmarks into saves. We've temporarily reverted to Bookmarks.

- All saves, private notes, saved lists, and migrated bookmarks are unavailable. They are still saved in the database and will be available again when we turn Saves back on.
- All unmigrated bookmarks are currently available while Saves is disabled and Bookmarks is turned on. When we turn Saves on again, we'll resume the migration.

The migration was partially applied and will resume once we've fixed the performance issues and turned Saves back on.

- Some network sites were completely migrated, and your bookmarks were successfully turned into saves in the "For later" list. These migrated saves are unavailable until Saves is turned back on.
- Some network sites were not yet migrated at all, and your bookmarks are untouched. These bookmarks are available as they were before the Saves launch.
- Stack Overflow was the only site partially migrated

  - Around 360k bookmarks were turned into saves
  - Around 14mil bookmarks are still bookmarks

We will post updates on this Meta post as well as on [Stack Status](https://www.stackstatus.net/).

---

#### Update Oct 4

Saves is now officially live on Stack Overflow and across Stack Exchange sites! The migration process will take some time to process as there are millions of bookmarked questions to migrate over. If you’re not seeing any questions you previously bookmarked, that means they haven’t been processed yet.

---

**TL;DR:** We're always working to make knowledge more accessible and easier to reuse, so we're excited to announce that we're making some feature updates to facilitate that. **Later this quarter, Bookmarks are being renamed to Saves, as well as getting a suite of upgrades to make the feature more useful and robust.**

To better understand how the community reuses knowledge, we've conducted a study on bookmarking habits, asked in the general survey how users interact with saved content, and looked through Meta posts to better understand how the Bookmarks feature is used and what needs we can serve better.

In the survey, 62% of respondents reported saving content for future use. One of the surprising uses we learned about was users creating an ad-hoc to-do list with their bookmarks. We also made use of Meta to look through community requests, including requests for [better organization](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3912/better-bookmarks-formerly-called-favorites-organisation), [being able to save answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1569/is-there-any-way-to-favorite-bookmark-an-answer), and even community-supported projects to add [notes to your saved content](https://stackapps.com/questions/6215/favourites-enhancer-tag-favourites-and-add-personal-notes). We felt we had enough feedback to seriously upgrade this experience and build out those desired paths with native support.

An overview of the new features you'll see with Saves:

- The ability to save answers
- The ability to create and manage custom lists to better organize saved content
- The ability to create private notes on saved posts
- The `in:saves` search operator (which only shows your own saved posts)

[image: Screenshot of the new "Saves" tab of an imaginary user's Stack Overflow profile page. It displays the new Saves heading in the heading bar.]

Here we get to show off the new dedicated tab on your profile page, which serves to increase visibility of the new knowledge reuse tools. On the left, you'll see the new "For later" section, which is where saved content defaults to. This was inspired by those users who used bookmarking as a way to create a to-do list for later site activities – but the sorting fun doesn't end there.

[image: Screenshot showing a custom list of saved posts on an imaginary user's Stack Overflow profile page. It displays an example of a private note on a saved post.]

Not only can you create multiple saved lists, but now you can also leave specific private notes for each saved question or answer. Use this as you see fit – collect thoughts, remind yourself why you saved a post in the first place, or draft responses. These notes are private to you, as are all of your lists and saves.

---

### FAQs

**What will happen to my existing bookmarks?**

We will be migrating over your existing bookmarks into the default “For later” Saves list. Once we enable the Saves feature, the migration process will take some time to process as there are millions of bookmarked questions to migrate over. If you’re not seeing any questions you previously bookmarked, that means they haven’t been processed yet.

**What sites will the Saves feature be available on?**

The Saves feature will be available network-wide on Stack Overflow and the Stack Exchange sites. However, Stack Overflow for Teams is not included in the initial rollout.

**Can I save a post to multiple lists?**

Currently, we are only allowing a post to be saved to a single list.

**Will my saved posts and lists be public?**

Nope! When we launch, all of the saved posts, custom lists, and private notes you create will be private moving forward. The existing Bookmarks tab on your network profile page will also be rebranded to Saves and made private.

**Are you adding any new badges?**

Absolutely! With the ability to save answers now, we will be adding two new badges for you to earn: Favorite Answer (Silver Badge) and Stellar Answer (Gold Badge), awarded when answers are saved by 25 and 100 users, respectively. The [badge list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges) will be updated to reflect these new additions.

**What happens to the existing badges I’ve earned with the previous bookmarks feature?**

We will be carrying over the existing badge progress associated with the [Favorite Question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/33/favorite-question) and [Stellar Question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/34/stellar-question) badges.

**Can moderators see my saved posts and private notes?**

Moderators will not be able to see or interact with your saved posts and private notes.

**What happens if a post I saved has been deleted?**

We will be preserving the existing behavior: If you have the [access to moderator tools](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) privilege, you will be able to see deleted posts in your saved lists. If you haven't earned this privilege yet, you will only be able to view deleted posts that you have authored.

**What changes will be made to search?**

We are removing the ability for users to search other users’ saved posts. The current search operators `inbookmarks:mine` and `inbookmarks:<userid>` will no longer yield any results. Users can now search their own saved posts using the `in:saves` search operator. The [Help Center page on searching](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/searching) will be updated to reflect this change.

**What happens to my saved posts if I have multiple accounts that need to be merged together?**

If you have saved posts in both accounts, your saved lists and posts will be merged together when the accounts are merged.

**What changes will be made to the user profile and network profile pages?**

On your user profile page, the Bookmarks section under Activity > Summary will be hidden now that we have a prominent menu item and Saves will be private. Additionally, the Bookmarks tab on the network profile pages will also be hidden as we re-evaluate how this will work with answers being supported now. We apologize for any inconvenience this may cause and will provide future updates on this.

---

We're really excited to address so many requests as part of this upcoming upgrade. Let us know what you think of the new features!

Comment: One edge case - if memory serves, if you have posted an answer to a question, and the question is deleted, you should be able to see the question. It might make sense to have these visible to the user in saves - not just mod-visible posts.

Comment: _"Will my saved posts and lists be public? Nope!"_ [Finally!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/379445/348196). Thank you!!

Comment: Is the name set in stone? _Saves_ reads like a verb (Mary saves money) and `in:saves` just makes no semantic sense to me, I would expect `in:saved` or `is:saved` instead.

Comment: The link at the beginning "[being able to save answers](/q/140778)" currently links to a [status-declined] post [Can there be an option to keep your list of bookmarks private?](/q/140778). Is that the correct link for that text? I can't seem to find where there's a request for the ability to bookmark answers there.

Comment: Related feature requests: the "**Favorites Tab**" section of this answer: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/319375/help-us-improve-the-user-profile-and-settings/319449#319449 Would very much love to see all of these requets/concerns addressed here.

Comment: I was about to downvote and explain that "Bookmarks" are a much more simple and known term, and "Saves" is too vague, **however**, then I read further to discover you're turning this into something much much bigger. Kudos!

Comment: Will Saved posts be available via SEDE? It's very helpful to see who has bookmarked a post currently. I really hope that we (or at least mods) can still see who bookmarked a post and when.

Comment: @terdon Saves is used as a noun in many cases (e.g. sports "how many saves does this pitcher have"; gaming "your saves [read:saved games] are stored in this folder", etc.), but I agree something like "saved questions" or "saved posts" would be much better/more clear.

Comment: The concept sounds good, but the name is horrible.

Comment: @TylerH yes of course it is, but in the absence of context it just really feels odd to me. More importantly, an item that has been saved isn't something a native speaker (or at least _this_ native speaker) would ever refer to as "a save". I would perhaps call the action of saving it _a save_ but once saved, whatever it is that was saved is not _a save_ itself. If I grab my hat just as it was flying overboard, you might say "nice save!", but you would be referring to the action I took to save it and not to the hat itself.

Comment: @terdon Yes, a save file referred to as a save is colloquial to video games pretty exclusively, to my knowledge (though it is _quite_ common there). I think your suggestion `is:saved` is semantically the best option for search operators.

Comment: Ah yes, a saved game is indeed _a save_. Fair point. But that's a very special case where the thing that was saved is actually a _saved_ game file. Something that lets you load your saved game. I would never call a page I saved for later _a save_ though.

Comment: @TylerH I'm fine with either `in:saves` or `in:saved` but I'm strongly against `is:saved` because currently, the `is` operator is used exclusively for post _types_.

Comment: Finally... mods know one less thing about the user :)

Comment: Can staff see the Saves of all users?

Comment: It's not clear why the rename is necessary. Bookmarks are already things that users have saved for future revisiting. That's why we renamed the feature from the original Favorites to Bookmarks, because Favorites didn't make sense for how it was used in practices. But it's not clear how we went from confirming that feedback in the survey to wanting to rename the feature to something more generic and confusing. Why is Saves better than Bookmarks here?

Comment: @animuson that's worthy of new answer, having better chance to get response and making it easier to follow as well. (Personally I thought the same at first, but then realized it's a good idea to make it clear this new thing has much more to it than before)

Comment: That is great news! Especially the multiple list feature (though the same could have been achieved with a tagging system (like for (ordinary) questions)).

Comment: Does this mean the bookmark 'vote' type (`VoteTypeId = 5`) will go away, or will saves continue to be stored as votes?

Comment: @HenryEcker good catch re: the "being able to save answers" link. That was a mistake and it has been corrected. Thank you for bringing this to our attention.

Comment: @RandomPerson that's correct. I'm not sure if this was addressed before (unrelated to Saves) but we're operating on a fiscal year with the current 2nd quarter (July to September) ending in September.

Comment: @RandomPerson regarding your question re: whether staff can see saved posts for all users, the short answer is no, not from the new user interface. Only users who are logged into their own accounts can view their saved posts.

Comment: Old bookmarked questions aren't necessarily good. I've bookmarked some very ordinary questions because they have a great answer. And in the days before the Follow feature, I'd often bookmark bad questions that I wanted to downvote if they weren't improved, or delete-vote when they became eligible. I usually unbookmark those, but I don't always remember to do that.

Comment: @tan Just in case you didn't notice, big parts of this are already in production, causing lots of confusion.

Comment: I honestly believed this is going to happen soon (like really soon, before end of quarter, which was today). Well, sometimes even I can be fooled, which I admit is an achievement.

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard I'm pleased to announce that Saves is now officially live on Stack Overflow and across the network sites!

Comment: Stop! Yes you!!! Don't add a comment before reading the first few lines of this post!

Comment: I kinda wish that the naming suggestion could've been taken into account......

Comment: Okay, the transition is a bit bumpy (I'd have put a temporary note on the Saves tab "Your old bookmarks will show up here once we're done migrating them"), but it sounds like you've really added a lot of features. Nice job! (Also, when a new version is so different from the previous one, you kinda gotta give it a new name, to forestall ambiguity. I'll probably still think of them as bookmarks, but "saves" seems reasonable to me.)

Comment: @tanj92 good luck fixing it, sounds like issue with sheer amount of data which you couldn't really test.

Comment: `We've temporarily reverted back to Bookmarks.` - Maybe, but the Bookmark page is empty; so now we have neither.

Comment: @Rob As written in the post, **"migrated bookmarks" will be unavailable.** This is  a feature and not a bug :)

Comment: @TheMaster, then they should have migrated the bugs instead; at least this addresses the issue of not being able to search my saves, so it *did* fix one omission.

Comment: Will there be a way to move Saves out of "For Later" but still keep them in "All Saves"? I was using the bookmark feature precisely as a way of bookmarking posts, not knowing if I'd need to reference them again, or how many times. "For Later" sounds like the Amazon/eBay trolley "Save For Later", and creates - to me at least - the impression that a saved post will be visited precisely one more time in the short-term future - which isn't the way I use bookmarks at all.

Comment: You can - it lets you create custom lists - and showed everything when I was messing with it

Comment: We need a new red moderator only [tag:status-retired] tag for the [Bookmarks FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/53585/282094), and an edit to that webpage.

Comment: @Rob that sounds like a feature request for  the former

Comment: @Jou, it's a *hoping someone else will do it* for both; my posts here don't get enough votes to encourage me, compared to everywhere else - where voting over 10X more favorable.

Comment: Woke up to this fire! _I love the smell of website instability in the morning right before my vacation_. Scaling to the millions is always tricky... We are on the final stages of testing a PR to address this, all going well everything should be re-enabled in a few hours. We'll then resume migrations tonight, no data will be lost (soft-deletion FTW). Thank you for your patience folks, we're excited for you to see this new feature, and to work with you on constantly improving it over time. Apologies for the delay and any inconveniences this is causing.

Comment: Now I need to bookmark this post to see when everything's ready. Oh... hm...

Comment: @Michael _oh you..._ I see what you did there. In all seriousness though, feel free to bookmark this, any new bookmarks will also be migrated to Saves.

Comment: If you have suddenly decided to get rid of bookmarks without asking, and now want me to spend my time making notes on certain questions/answers because Stack's search engine is so poor... are you going to give me a way to back up these notes (on my computer) in case you decide to get rid of this feature later also without asking?

Comment: @Michael I know that you were just joking. But if anyone really wants to follow developments on this, the correct course of action is to *follow* the question so you get notifications when something changes.

Comment: Saves are back up, we'll be monitoring and migrating bookmarks slowly. Official comments on it coming soon to the main post.

Comment: @MarkSetchell The https://stackoverflow.com/legal/gdpr/request export should contain these

Comment: @FelippeRangel could recent messing at Stack Overflow break [auto-deletion scripts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/420707/839601) aka Roomba over there?

Comment: @FelippeRangel thanks, any chance for details about what went wrong, aka post mortem post?

Comment: @bad_coder there are still quite a few list items without a full stop. What's the point adding one, leaving the others without it?

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard full sentence vs sentence fragment.

Comment: Until what date will this post be monitored for new answers? (@FelippeRangel)

Comment: @gnat not the case, the Saves feature is it's own architecture separate from all of that (unlike Bookmarks which were technically just votes). If there's a bug in Roomba it's something else.

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard I'll leave it to the people handling the post's discretion, if they want to share they will. But TL/DR is that our code had some hard-to-test holes that only showed up when we threw millions of rows at it. After that and some index optimization at the database level we were ok.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog I don't think we have a set date yet on when we will stop monitoring this particular post (if ever), but even after this post is deprecated we will keep evolving the Saves feature taking into account the data already shared in this post, plus any other posts that come in the future, of course.

Comment: While I understand that saves of specific user are not public, why can't we see total number of saves for given question/answer?

Comment: Sure, make this all wonderful **now**, *after* I have already bookmarked over 2000 questions on over 75 different SE sites! ;)

Comment: @Sil same reason they dropped details from profile page: it saves them some work, and people didn't shout loud enough against the change. There's really no actual reason.

Answer (score 118):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) Keep the name of the feature as "Bookmarks/Bookmarking" or find a more appropriate term.

Maybe something along the lines of "Notebook" ([as suggested in the comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382019/bookmarks-have-evolved-into-saves/382032#comment1276231_382032)) would be a better name, which would lead to "save in my notebook", "saved items", and "in:notebook". It would also make sense as a name if the feature were further expanded to include other sorts of notes or information organization.

Expanding on what [terdon has already pointed out](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/382027/273494),

The [definition of save](https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/the-noun-for/save.html) as a noun:

> - In various sports, a block that prevents an opponent from scoring.
> - (baseball) When a relief pitcher comes into a game leading by 3 points
> - (runs) or less, and his team wins while continually being ahead.
> - (professional wrestling, slang) A point in a professional wrestling match when one or more wrestlers run to the ring to aid a fellow wrestler who is being beaten.
> - **(computing) The act, process, or result of saving data to a storage medium.**
> - (role-playing games) A saving throw.

This is not a good way to describe bookmarking a page so you can refer to it later. It implies making a copy that isn't going to change. Using "save" as a noun in the context of saving a link in a list is likely to confuse some people. If I "save" a web page in my browser, it downloads it to my disk.

Sure, most technical people fluent in English won't have trouble understanding it, but why not just continue to use the most appropriate and well-understood term?

> [bookmark noun (COMPUTER)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/learner-english/bookmark)
> an address on the Internet that you record so that you can quickly find something again:
> *Add this website to your bookmarks.*

I can't find a learner's dictionary that has the computing sense of "save" as a noun. The only definition they have is the sporting one: "block that prevents an opponent from scoring".

I understand wanting to differentiate this new feature from the old style bookmarks, but I don't think that is a good enough reason to avoid using the most commonly understood terms. Organizing bookmarks into lists and annotating them is not a new thing. There are probably good translations already in place for bookmarking terms.

It is weird that the [bookmark icon](https://cdn.onlinewebfonts.com/svg/img_16800.png) was retained for "Saves" instead of the [floppy disk icon](https://cdn.onlinewebfonts.com/svg/img_401874.png) normally associated with saving. If the concept were really that different, I assume retaining the old icon would be a source of confusion.

Comment: I went trawling for a comment or post to upvote, but I didn't find one. So here: I _do not care_ about the change in nomenclature.

Comment: @Michael Do you care if it stays *Bookmarks* or becomes something other than *Saves*? You're entitled to not care... just seeking clarification on whether you particularly like *Saves* or just don't care what the feature is named.

Comment: Great question. If it were changed to "bulldozers" or "colorless green ideas," I'd maybe object. But between "Bookmarks" and "Saves," it just doesn't rise to the level that it bothers me. And I'm a little surprised to see two of the top three answers specifically decrying the name change.

Comment: Something like "Saved Content" would be better grammatically but is obviously less succinct. Saves is just pretty jarring to me. I'd even prefer something like... save to your "binder," "diary," or "notebook" since there's additional features coming to supplement this, such as notes and new ways to organize your saved content.

Comment: @Pluto I like the idea of referring to it as a notebook or some similar thing. It would pave the way for future enhancements. For example, organizing drafts of questions or answers you're writing, keeping citation links you use a lot for certain topics, etc. *Saves* doesn't really inspire people to think of what it could evolve into, and any further evolution is probably going to require yet more renaming churn.

Comment: @Michael Do you not care for yourself or for everyone? How about other groups of people, such as non-native English speakers for example?

Comment: @DavidG Anyone's entitled to opinions that differ from mine. I think it's fine to hold those opinions on behalf of oneself or on behalf of other people. Sometimes I make assertions on behalf of others, but here only for myself. What's a little disconcerting is that this is the second @-comment (the first apparently deleted) suggesting that my _lack of preference_ is rooted in disregard for other groups. I'm trying to assume best intentions, but maybe I need to assume harder.

Comment: @Michael I think it was a good thing for you to express your opinion in a comment so that others can upvote it if they hold a similar view. I deleted my comment because I realized after writing it that I was just trying to talk you out of your opinion which I just said you were entitled to :) I obviously disagree with you but in the grand scheme of things, I don't really care enough to pick a fight over it.

Comment: @Michael out of curiosity, were you already familiar with the use of _save_ as a countable noun such as "video game saves"? Maybe it is less jarring to people who were already familiar with it. I know I found it very jarring (enough to post an entire answer!) despite being a techie and a native English speaker. So maybe it seems fine to you because you're already used to the term? Note: not trying to change your mind here, just curious.

Comment: @terdon Yes. It's also a countable noun in sports, but the Stack Exchange use more directly mirrors video games saves.

Answer (score 68):

> Moderators will not be able to see or interact with your saved posts and private notes

Bookmarks were an important tool in the process of identifying voting fraud. I understand that mods should not interact with users' saved posts, but is there a good reason why mods cannot see them?

Comment: If it's indeed an important tool for identifying voting fraud, I'd say show mods a list of _all_ the user's saved posts _uncatogorized_ (and obviously without the private notes). In other words, similar to what we have now.

Comment: FWIW, mods can also see someone else's followed posts (which are actually private to anyone). Thus, I agree, I don't see why saved posts can't be seen by mods.

Comment: Plus, with the introduction of more badges, there might be badge fraud. (I don't know what type of person would have 25 or 100 accounts for this, but I can't be surprised by anything anymore.)

Comment: @Laurel I have seen at least one that did it already...

Comment: There was a user request for private content saving and we thought that the more default understanding of "content saved for me" is private.

Comment: It should be private in the same sense that followed posts are private. Mods should be able to see it so that they can investigate abuse.

Comment: @Salmon_of_Wisdom If a user really wants *private* content saving they can use a browser bookmark; no one but them will know it is bookmarked. I think mods have a need to be able to see what users bookmark and how they organize them. Maybe hide private notes from mods (like how Strava has a private notes field only the uploader can see for runs or bike rides you upload), but mods at least need to see the ones that are bookmarked and in what lists.

Answer (score 68):

This is a great feature, thank you! I just don't quite understand why you need a name change from something clearly understandable (bookmarks) to something very confusing. "Saves", to me, reads like a verb, not a noun. Yes, we have saves in various sports, but that refers to the action of saving and not to the object that was saved.

I would perhaps call the action of saving something *a save* but once saved, whatever it is that was saved is not *a save* itself. If I grab my hat just as it was flying overboard, you might say "nice save!", but you would be referring to the action I took to save it and not to the hat itself.

The only other case I can think of where *save* is used as a countable noun referring to the saved item is saved games in computer games. But that is a very, very specific context and isn't really representative of how the word is used by the broader public.

To me, `in:saves` is semantically jarring and I wouldn't know what a "Saves" section would contain. If you want to change the name to signify that this is more than just a bookmark, can't we go for something like "Saved" or "Saved Posts"?

We could then search for `is:saved` or `in:saved` and everything would be semantically clear and proper.

Comment: Since we're organizing these items into lists, I would prefer `inlist:` and be able to specify a list identifier or "all".

Comment: I don't know if is:saved is quite right... we have is:question is:answer but no is:mine is:accepted is:wiki ... granted the search syntax is all over the place though.

Comment: @ColleenV fine by me, let's stick with `in:saved` then. What I really want to avoid is the `saves`.

Comment: Agreed. It's a very coderesque way to name it. Video games have "saves". What we're doing here is bookmarking. We don't get our own immutable copy of the post.

Comment: I'd just leave it at bookmarks, it's a perfectly fine name for the feature.  Putting bookmarks in lists/folders/something is not new, and since they also become private with this change the name fits even better.

Comment: Using "saves" like that seems odd to me too. Maybe it's an American thing (I'm Australian). It's a bit like calling questions "asks"...

Comment: We don't currently have any plans to change the name away from Saves. This is not a unique use of the word in the web space nor in tech. We're sure that most users will understand and the helpdesk is there for folks needing assisstance.

Comment: For what it's worth, @Salmon_of_Wisdom, I am both a native English speaker and very much in the world of tech and although I can figure out what you mean, it really is strange and semantically jarring. Given that at this point, a majority of SE sites are not about computer stuff, it does seem like a weird choice to use relatively obscure gaming jargon.  _shrugs_

Comment: @Salmon_of_Wisdom just because it is possible to explain a term in a help center doesn’t mean there won’t be a huge mental dissonance to overcome. Terms like ‘bookmarks’ or ‘notes’ or ‘markers’ cover the concept far better and make it easier for new users to get to understand what that feature among many does. The sites are overwhelming enough without this extra burden.

Comment: @Salmon_of_Wisdom I don't understand why y'all want to make things harder than they have to be. Renaming bookmarks (again) is a lot of work for not a lot of value to your users. Using "Saves" instead of something like "Clippings" (which has a definition for the correct sense of the word in learner's dictionaries) is going to have negative value to a significant portion of your users. I realize that y'all are in that place where no amount of user feedback is going to change your minds. I'm guessing y'all think you're mostly done with the work to do the rename.

Comment: It's definitely not an American thing. If I saw "Saves" in this context, I'd have no earthly idea what it means. This is a terrible name. I didn't think they could do worse than calling a service Collectives, but somehow they've managed. At least Collectives was descriptive. Colleen made the point somewhere that coders and/or technical people might understand this. Well, I'm both of those, deeply so, and yet it's not clear to me. Terdon made the point that "Saves" is a gamer thing. That's possible; I'm not a gamer, so I don't recognize that idiom. Maybe pick a name that is universal and clear?

Comment: @CodyGray A *save* is something in football (that's Association Football, or soccer): it's what goalkeepers make when stopping the ball from passing the goal line into the net.

Comment: @AndrewLeach yes, that's the same use as in the second paragraph, the action of saving something but not the thing itself.

Comment: @Salmon_of_Wisdom I don't think I've seen "Saves" used elsewhere, do you have other examples?

Answer (score 31):

> **What happens if a post I saved has been deleted?**
>
> We will be preserving the existing behavior: If you have the access to moderator tools privilege, you will be able to see deleted posts in your saved lists. If you haven't earned this privilege yet, you will only be able to view deleted posts that you have authored.

I feel like this turns the ‘save’ name into a misnomer.  Usually, when I save something, I can trust that it remains there until I choose to get rid of it (unless there is an accident).

I don’t particularly care which way this is resolved, though; I’m rather indifferent to the feature, as I don’t use it much (worst case, I can just switch to browser bookmarks).  Not that the changes are otherwise bad.

Comment: It's exactly like browser bookmarks: if the page you've bookmarked is deleted, then it's no longer accessible via the bookmark. The only differences here are: (a) it has an inferior UI that you've never seen before, so you have to learn it for the first time, unlike what is built into your browser; and (b) it has a confusing name that doesn't reflect what it does and isn't used in that context or to mean that thing anywhere else in the world, so you have no chance of figuring it out without just trying it (learning through failure).

Comment: @CodyGray If it's walks like a bookmark and it quacks like a bookmark, why is it still called "saves"? I'm having a hard time understanding the logic...

Comment: You and me both, @iBug. I guess Stack Overflow didn't want to let Jesus be the only one who Saves.

Comment: @ibug - trying to beat a dead horse back to life with branding, by doing the least work possible, like changing the name of a button which does both for them, all the while being a better data collection platform. I missed the part when favorites became bookmarks; now it's saves which work just like my browser. Except now it's all *'in house'*. - How does your name begin with a lowercase i followed by a capital letter, and you don't know this?

Comment: "Can staff see the Saves of all users?" – Random Person Sep 13 at 15:42. - I mean, it's on their computer; *somebody* gets to see it. I want to be able to make personal notes anywhere. Except that goes against the (true, unadulterated) SE model. - My favorite part is the popup. Because who doesn't like popups for some shit they didn't ask for?

Answer (score 31):

> Will my saved posts and lists be public? Nope! […] The existing Bookmarks tab on your network profile page will also be rebranded to Saves and made private.

Oh no! [This breaks my workflow](https://xkcd.com/1172/)… I think public bookmarks are a good way of showcasing important questions, e.g. for lists of canonical (duplicate-target) topics. This was very helpful for curating content. I don't need no private lists, the [followed posts feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661/183280) solved that for me just fine. So I have a

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

Please allow making individual lists public and searchable. It doesn't need to be (and probably shouldn't be) public by default, but it's an important aspect of the current bookmarking system to keep as an option.

Comment: *"I don't need no private lists"* So what? By default things should be private. If the user want they may have the option to make things public but by default things should be private.

Comment: @JasonLiam That's exactly what I am proposing. I don't have anything against private lists, I agree they're the better default, it's just that I personally have no need for them.

Comment: An option to make some lists public could evolve into a great tool for both annotation and collaboration. Annotation: Another way to navigate the Stack Overflow maze (examples: 1) FAQs for a particular area in JavaScript 2) A list of important questions to review first for beginners in X (e.g., common pitfalls)). Collaboration: For example, 'Help me find the canonical questions for this list of low-scored questions with low-quality answers'. The *follower* numbers for such lists could be used as a rough indication of their quality or importance.

Comment: If lists themselves could items in lists, this could create a web and aid discoverability.

Comment: I have shared a link to my bookmarks on one of the SE sites on a post on another website as some kind of a list of "here are things on this specific topic that are really nice to check out". It's probably from a few years ago but people still occasionally find it. Now that link is broken >_<

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum I'd rather have a markdown description text for the list (which could also contain links to other things) than to have lists containing lists

Comment: Not sure this justifies a separate post, but I would even suggest another step forward to ***collaborative*** lists. i.e. not only they are public, they can be edited by multiple users. This even further supports the curating efforts and having a duplicate list for a specific subject curated by multiple people can be really (really) useful!

Comment: @Tomerikoo Reminds me of the still-relevant feature request of making the tag wiki more visible. Such collaborative lists would be very useful for FAQs, but they already kind of exist, e.g. [for Python](//stackoverflow.com/tags/python/info); unfortunately, nobody that needs this list will ever find it. There’s also the [tag search sorted by “Frequent”](//stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python?sort=frequent), but it’s not easily editable.

Answer (score 30):

Some questions about private notes:

1. Will there be a character limit on private notes? If so, what is it?
2. Will mini (comment style) markdown be supported in private notes?

   - When I save dupe targets (in my current system), I also include a snip of the solution so that I know what the target is for.
     *e.g.* my note for [How to apply a function to two columns of Pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13331698) currently looks something like:

     `df['Col3'] = df.apply(lambda r: func(r['Col1'], r['Col2'], axis=1)`

     This allows me to search my page for the solution to find the corresponding target. For this reason (among others), things like code formatting in private notes would be very helpful.

Comment: 1) Currently, 500 characters. If this turns out to be too few, we can change it.
2) Currently no support for mini markdown.

Comment: @Salmon_of_Wisdom A natural question along the same lines is whether private notes will suport [MathJax](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/mathjax/info) - on the sites that use MathJax. Fingers crossed to see some of this implemented at some future point. (I did not want to post this a separate answer - since comments support MathJax, this probably falls under the notes being "comment style".)

Answer (score 28):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

**Allow for searching in specific lists.**

I currently have bookmarked a lot of questions that are canonicals for different topics, so I can quickly find them and link them, when needed.

I do love the idea of being able to have a separate list of items that are of personal interest, not something to link to often. However, I would want to be able to choose which list I search through - whether to search for a canonical to use as a duplicate or for something else.

Comment: Great idea, but probably is best covered by `insaves:mine` and `"specific text string"`; there's no way they can add support for infinitely customizable list names chosen by users.

Comment: @TylerH How about adding a search field on the "Saves" page that searches in whatever list is currently open (or all saves if no list is selected)? And then `in:saves` would just work as a shortcut.

Comment: @TylerH "*there's no way they can add support for infinitely customizable list names chosen by users*" pretty sure it's possible. YouTube doesn't stop me from making as many lists of videos as I want. On the technical side, I'm sure it's essentially a list you can give a name to. Custom filters kind of do that already - it's a collection of tags to search and you can name it. You can make many of them, too.

Comment: I also would like to see inlist:listname or inlist:all and just dump "saves" entirely.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Once we are able to understand the usage of this new feature post-launch we will revisit the requests from Meta for future iterations.

Comment: @VLAZ It's not about how many lists you make, it's about the system creating keywords to use for searching them. If I make a list called "purpleSucks" should I be able to search `in:saves list:purpleSucks`? Not likely.

Comment: @TylerH  It should be something like  `in:saves.purpleSucks`. It should select `saves` and then subselect `purpleSucks` and start the search.  Why do you say not likely?

Comment: @TheMaster I am aware of several sensible ways it work from a front-end perspective. That's not my concern. My concern is with storing a potentially infinite number of custom searches in their database. Based on how they store the custom filters it could be not a scalable thing. If they have the table architected such that they only need one new column and can save each custom filter as a row, then sure that might work fine. But if they store filter options as columns... yeah no.

Answer (score 25):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

Lists with items in them could prompt before you can delete them.

People do dumb things. Since you can't really recover a list, or the items in them, it might be nice to warn folks that everything in a list that's deleted is *gone*. This wouldn't make sense with an empty list but the moment there's an item, and especially an annotation for the item, letting people know about potential data loss seems like a good idea.

Comment: I created a report [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/395805/1242908) that removing an item from a Saves list silently deletes any attached private notes which is probably connected with deleting a list and all of its Saves.

Answer (score 25):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

Can there be a way to undo un-saving a post?

At the moment, accidentally clicking the button leaves you with no recourse:

[image: Unsaving a save shows a banner that "(Post) removed from saves", but gives the user no means to undo that action, and no way to access the post again to resave it]

I really like how this works with Followed posts, where the "X" turns into a "Follow" button, and you can undo your mistake just as easily as you made it.

[image: Refollowing an unfollowed post]

Comment: I agree, just lost 1 save without warning.

Comment: My userscript [SavedPostsHelper.user.js](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/blob/master/SavedPostsHelper.user.js) now adds an undo button for resaving. It also already adds bulk-moving checkboxes in your saved lists, and a quick-move dropdown in the toast immediately after saving a post in Q&A.

Answer (score 25):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

There should be some way to check *which list* a saved post is in, and *what private notes* you have given it — from the post's page.

Currently, you can see that a post *is saved* on its page, but to see *what list* it is in, or to *read the notes* you have to find the post in the **All saves list**.

#### Mock-up:

[image: mockup: saved post showing (circled): which list it is in, and the private note below]

Comment: related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/384115/997587

Comment: Related: [See private notes on saved posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/387120/see-private-notes-on-saved-posts)

Answer (score 23):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)/[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

#### You told me about the new feature; no need to repeat on every single site.

Every time I open a post on any SE site, I get this popover message:

[image: A popover saying: "New! Save questions or answers and organize your favorite content. Learn more."]

...unless I have previously dismissed it *on that specific site*.

I appreciate that this is a new cool feature and we want users who aren't following Meta to be informed about it. The only problem is that dismissing the popover only stops it from appearing on the current site, so one would have to dismiss it at least<sup>*</sup> once on every site upon visiting, which is pretty annoying.

---

<sup>*</sup> <sub>It will appear more than once on a single site if you open multiple posts before dismissing it.</sub>

Comment: Yeah, this is so awfully annoying. I clicked on this meta post exactly to point it out or upvote an answer that already did. I closed this at least 5 times just today.

Comment: I really don't get why they did this particular regression. I seem to remember a different feature they introduced a couple years ago as well which had the exact same notification and the exact same annoying prompt on every single new site.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. For now, the popover has been disabled on all sites except for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @tanj92 it also shows here on Meta. I also don't like that it returns after logging out. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/383257/dont-show-the-new-we-have-saves-now-popup-on-every-session-please

Comment: @CodeCaster the Saves popover has been disabled on Stack Overflow. We do not have any current plans to re-enable it for Saves. We appreciate the feedback Meta has shared and will take this into consideration for future popovers we deploy.

Answer (score 22):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)[status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review)

I think it would be desirable to have the right side of the Saves MY LISTS display the number of posts saved in each list item. This would also be consistent with the Communities in the User profile where the right side displays reputation per site. (Overall most listings in the User profile have numbers, the Saves list itself is feeling partially empty.)

[image]

Comment: numbers should be right-aligned

Comment: @ElementsinSpace it's my rendition of a sampled [freehand circle](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/138031) oscillator inside a rectangle envelope.

Comment: I like the numbers where they are.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, this has been ticketed for a future release.

Answer (score 19):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

Change the wording "You have no saved items" shown when a list is empty:

[image: empty list screenshot]

This is misleading as it implies no saved items at all. Please change to:

> You have no saved items in this list

Answer (score 18):

[support](/questions/tagged/support)

Will I be able to search the "private note" content using the `in:saves` search operator?

Or will there be a separate operator for the "private note" search?

Comment: At launch, the in:saves operator will only return a list of saved posts (questions and answers). Private notes will not be returned as part of the search results. Once we can better understand usage with this new and improved feature we can determine priority for future requests.

Comment: @tanj92 aka "Start a feature request after this is live". :)

Comment: @tanj92 that’s not what is being asked. You are talking about what is shown for each search hit. The question here asks if the private note content is *indexed* and can be targeted directly to search in.

Answer (score 17):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

It's possible to move a saved post to a new list, not enter a name for the new list, and click 'Done'. In that case, nothing happens, except that you get a notification

> Question saved to .

[image]

[image]

Comment: This should be resolved now. When you try to move a saved post to a new list without entering a name an error toast message with "List name cannot be empty." is displayed. Thanks for reporting!

Answer (score 17):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

Can you add the ability to move saves to a new list in-bulk?

Since everything was migrated to the "For later" list, I'm now wanting to sort my saves into better-fitting lists.

But I have 65 of them on this site, and each one I want to move requires 5 clicks and several seconds to send to a new list... while a somewhat minor complaint, I can't imagine what this process would be like for someone with *hundreds* of such saves.

It would be really, really useful to be able to e.g. click a checkbox next to a bunch of saves in a given list and then move all of the selected ones to another list at once.

Comment: I think this is the same FR [as this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/382658) but you posted earlier.

Comment: My userscript [SavedPostsHelper.user.js](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/blob/master/SavedPostsHelper.user.js) adds bulk-moving checkboxes.

Answer (score 16):

> **What will happen to my existing bookmarks?**
> We will be migrating over your existing bookmarks into the default “For later” Saves list. Once we enable the Saves feature, the migration process will take some time to process as there are millions of bookmarked questions to migrate over. If you’re not seeing any questions you previously bookmarked, that means they haven’t been processed yet.

Why can't I access my existing bookmarks per the old interface, until they are migrated? Why do I have to trust, for an unspecified length of time (which has already been many hours), that I will eventually get access again to my hundreds of bookmarks (most of which are **essential** to how I use Stack Overflow nowadays, since they make it feasible for me to work around the terrible site search and find the canonical duplicates I want more quickly)? Why do site searches using `inbookmarks:mine` ignore that term silently?

Comment: I honestly don't understand the logic behind this migration. What should've happened is 1) Copy (not move) the data in bookmarks into Saves. 2) Enable Saves and disable the Bookmarks feature (not remove bookmarks). 3) Wait for a while to make sure that everything works as expected and only then, bookmarks can be removed. Otherwise, Saves can be temporarily disabled and Bookmarks re-enabled **with all data preserved** while they investigate.

Comment: One drawback with copy not move is the time lag: you could create new bookmarks which would not be copied. That's *probably* less of an inconvenience than losing access to all of the migrated bookmarks while it's stalled and turned off.

Comment: Every data migration I've had to go through (except for that one real shit show that I don't want to talk about) has started with a checkpoint to migrate most of the data over prior to everything going "live" which is then updated with incremental migrations to catch up. This is why I'm far more likely to use a more general bookmarking service than a custom feature. I can back them up if they're important to me.

Comment: @AndrewLeach They could prevent changing bookmarks during the migration if that would be an issue, though it would be good for them to give a warning first, and incrementally updating with new changes would be ideal

Answer (score 16):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

##### New Saves dialogs are draggable but cannot be moved

The three new Saves dialogs: "Edit list", "New List", and "Move to" would all appear to be draggable as the cross arrows pointer appears over the title, like so:

[image: image of cross arrow pointer on Move to dialog]

However, these dialogs cannot be dragged.

##### Tabbing to the title of the new dialogs

A connected issue may be that it is possible to tab to the title using the tab key, and a black border appears when the title has the focus.

It appears that the dialog cannot be moved using the keyboard either (pressing up or down arrow scrolls the underlying page and pressing left or right arrow does nothing). This may create accessibility issues.

In the image below, the red circles indicate the tab stops:

[image: tabbing to the title of the Move to dialog]

This was tested on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/)

Comment: This should be fixed now. Please let us know if it's still an issue on your end. Marking as status-completed. Thanks!

Answer (score 15):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [plurals](/questions/tagged/plurals) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

All item lists (with 1 member) say "1 saved items":

[image]

Comment: Thanks for reporting, the translations hadn't gone out for this one yet. Should be all fixed now!

Answer (score 14):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) Set a default list other than “For later.” Or, be able to rename the existing default list.

I'd say 90% of my bookmarks are to keep for permanent reference, and 10% are “for later.” Hence, I'd like the save button to put something into my “Reference” list by default, and then have the option to move it.

Currently my options are:

- Move saves from For later to Reference 9/10 times. That's 5 clicks rather than 1.
- Use the For later as my reference list, and make a separate “actually for later” list. That's confusing.
- Ignore the whole feature and treat For later as classic bookmarks.

Comment: My userscript [SavedPostsHelper.user.js](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/blob/master/SavedPostsHelper.user.js) adds bulk-moving checkboxes in lists, and adds a quick-move dropdown in the toast immediately after saving a post.

Answer (score 14):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)[support](/questions/tagged/support)[status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)

Currently, the user count of people who've "Saved" a post is no longer shown. Is this intentional? Will the number be brought back in the post listing?

[image: Vote score and saves icon]

Formerly:

[image: Previous vote score and saves icon]

Comment: 99% sure it's on purpose because Saves are private, while Bookmarks and Favorites used to be public.

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard votes are also private yet vote scores are shown...

Comment: @bad_coder One provides useful info, the other provides absolutely nothing (people bookmarking something doesn't mean they're saving something because it's good)

Comment: @KevinB On the other hand, there are badges tied to the number of users that saved a question (and new corresponding badges for answers). Showing the number would help track the progress toward these for interested users.

Comment: Badges, that, award something that doesn't represent reality, of course. It can still be tracked within your profile.

Comment: @bad_coder the short answer to your question about whether this is intentional/by-design is yes. There are not current plans to bring this back with the Saves launch.

Comment: @tanj92 and the long answer? Is this declined, or is there still a chance it would be reconsidered, in the future?

Answer (score 14):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

##### There currently appears to be no way to add a post to an empty Saves list

Here is one way to reproduce this:

1. Click on the Saves button
2. Click on the + button and create two new Saves list named, for example: "one" and "two"

[image]

3. Click on the Saves icon next to an unsaved question or answer
4. Click on the "Manage" button in the toast message and click on "For later"
5. The drop down list does not show any empty Saves lists, namely, neither "one" nor "two are listed

[image]

Interestingly, if you click on "Create new list" and try to create a new list called "one", for example, then you will see the "List name already exists" error message after clicking "Done".

[image]

I suspect that this may have been working correctly at some time and this bug has been introduced recently. I believe that [another answer to this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/382685) shows that empty lists were possible at some point:

[image]

Comment: Basically the same thing happens if you have a non-empty list and remove the post(s) from your saves. Once the list is emptied, it is no longer shown in the dropdown when saving a question or an answer. (+1 from me - I planned to report this as a bug, but I did not find the time.)

Comment: @Martin Yes, that was in fact how I first saw the error message, but I forgot to add that method when writing the bug report.

Comment: Also reported on MSO: [Saves questions feature: cannot move question in created list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421681/8967612)

Comment: Thanks for reporting! This appears to be a recent bug, could have been affected from another bug we addressed. It's been ticketed in our backlog.

Comment: A fix has been deployed. Please let me know if you're still experiencing issues.

Comment: @tanj92 made my day :) I'm already enjoying the functionality!

Answer (score 13):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

Please let us delete lists without having to edit them first:

[image: mockup of delete list button]

Answer (score 13):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

Typing “in:saves” into the all-sites search box on https://stackexchange.com  doesn't work. The first time I tried it, it returned one result from MSE (if I remember correctly). Now, I get “an unexpected error occurred”. I would expect (or rather, hope) that it will give me saves from all sites.

Comment: AFAIK, [user operators](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/searching) syntax never works on network-wide search, e.g. `user:me`, `in:saves`, `intags:me`.

Comment: @MetaAndrewT. In that case, still would be nice to get an error message that says so.

Comment: related: [Can I view Saves from multiple SE Q&A sites in one place?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/386066/997587)

Answer (score 12):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)[status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review)

Minor quibble, but a bug nonetheless:

Attempting to un- or re-save a post that's *already* been un- or resaved errors out.

E.g. if you have multiple tabs open, and try to save the same post in each, the second time the action will show an error:

[image: Saving the same post in multiple browser tabs shows an error on the second tab]

For reference, with Followed posts, clicking the follow button just works on both tabs regardless.

Comment: This also happens when you go back some pages (via the browser back button) to re-save after accidentally removing a save.

Comment: Thanks for reporting. This might be considered an edge case but it's been ticketed, nonetheless.

Answer (score 12):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

Searching for `in:saves` on sites where one doesn't have any saved posts returns a list of all (non-deleted) posts ever created, rather than returning zero results:

[image: in:saves on Super User returns ~1.2m results]

Answer (score 12):

[status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review)

Ok. Lovely change.
Nice that all the bookmarks (previously named favorites) are **MOVED**.

But how do I access those moved items from the API??

I have an automation on the /users/{ids}/favorites which now returns NOTHING.
https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/favorites-on-users

> Get the questions bookmarked (previously known as "favorited") by
> users identified by a set of ids.

Did the API get left behind in the planning of this change or did I miss something?

Comment: I fear it is - with the mobile apps deprecated, updating the API is low on the priority list (if it will be updated at all - it's a non-trivial change, unlike the renaming of favorites to bookmarks).

Comment: And considering that Saves are private now, probably only [`/me/favorites`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/me-favorites) (or perhaps renamed to `/me/saves`) will be used...

Comment: As part of the Saves launch, I failed to communicate anything about the API in the FAQ section, however we have tickets created to do some investigation of the current API usage and determine what steps we need to take to either support the existing features (i.e. saved questions but only for your account) and/or potentially creating a new set of APIs for Saves. Once we have a plan finalized, we will communicate back to Meta.

Comment: Also asked about in a separate MSE post here: [API request for "favorites" now returning an empty list – is there a way to get something equivalent for saves?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/382991/335251) – the same official response is also posted as an answer there.

Answer (score 11):

[support](/questions/tagged/support)

Navigating to https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/saves/current works - it shows your own saves.

But the URL is inconsistent with how other user pages work: https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current *redirects* for me to https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/295232/glorfindel.

Is it on purpose that https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/saves/current does not redirect to https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/saves/295232?

Comment: Also, something I found interesting: clicking on the "Saves" tab of the user profile shows the "All saves" list by default (which makes sense to me); that list page is located at a URL of `/users/saves/<userID>/all`. However, the URL `/users/saves/current` itself specifically shows the "For later" list under Saves, because that list page is located at the URL `/users/saves/<userID>`.

Answer (score 11):

I get that there's a purpose in telling users about a new feature. But does it have to be done individually for every single Stack Exchange site? I've seen this box about 20 times already. Can't that check be network-wide? At the very least, meta sites don't need to display this when I've already seen it on their corresponding main site.

[image: Pop-up info dialog about the 'save' feature]

Comment: Yeah, they do it every time, despite numerous requests to not do it. Anything that includes dismissing a banner must be done on each site, over and over and over again.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. For now, the popover has been disabled on all sites except for Stack Overflow.

Comment: This may be a response to [41686d6564 stands w. Palestine's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382019/bookmarks-have-evolved-into-saves/382879#382879).

Comment: @tanj92 thanks, and hope one day it will be simple (code wise) to tie something to the user's network account, thus making such things easier to implement.

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum no, those are duplicate answers, it's common when there are lots of answers so it's hard to find if what you have to say was already said before.

Answer (score 10):

Regarding the Favorite Answer (Silver Badge) and Stellar Answer (Gold Badge) requirements, will the number of saves exclude saving by the OP? In other words, is it 25/100 saves *by people other than myself* for me to earn the badge on one of my answers? Or will saving my own answers contribute (or will it even be possible)?

Comment: If the existing behaviour of Favourite Question and Steller Question badges is anything to go by, then OP saves will be included.

Comment: I was able to get an official confirmation from a developer working on the feature: the OP is included as this maintains the current behavior of the existing badges.

Answer (score 10):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Editing/renaming the list for the second time (without refreshing the page) shows the old name:

[image: Demo]

Similarily, deleting the list after renaming it shows a toast message with the old name:

[image: Toast message: "Old name has been deleted from your lists"]

Comment: Thanks! This has been ticketed for review in the next sprint.

Comment: Yep. I ran into this problem today.

Comment: A fix has been deployed. As such, I've updated the tag to status-completed. Please let us know if you're still having issues. Thank you!

Answer (score 10):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Pressing "Cancel" after going to "Add private note" leaves a yellow div behind that doesn't go until the page is reloaded.

> [image]

Reproduced on Firefox 105 on Windows 10, and Chrome 106 on Android 13.

Comment: Thank you, I was able to replicate this on my end and it has been ticketed.

Comment: A fix has been deployed and I was able to verify on production. I'll be updating the tag to [status-completed]

Comment: I'm a big fan of the test string "lol" in this gif

Answer (score 9):

The proposed changes are neat, but I think you guys had a few changes leak out to production a bit early. The related badges for bookmarked questions (to be "saved" questions) currently have their descriptions changed from "bookmarked" (previously "favorited") to "saved". This has its own [dedicated bug report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/382099/622284).

[image: Image of the Favorite Question and Stellar Question badges with their descriptions having the "saved" verbiage instead of "bookmarked"]

This in concert with an out-of-nowhere design change to the Bookmark icon:

| Previous | New |
| --- | --- |
| [image: Old bookmark image] | [image: New bookmark image] |

... And the part where [the `/user/saves` endpoint is available to us](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/382102/622284) suggests that there are some commits leaking out that you didn't intend.

Were any these intentional? If not, I figured you would want to know that we're seeing these changes when we don't yet expect to.

Comment: I like the new icon a bit better (since the star was very hard to see), though I can't help but look at it and say *oh look, the [ELL](https://ell.stackexchange.com/) icon!*

Comment: The amount of churn we're going to see because they want to rename bookmarks yet again depresses me. We've already made [tag:favorites] a synonym of [tag:bookmarks] so questions about the old favorites feature can't be separated from questions about the bookmarks feature. I bet we're going to synonymize [tag:bookmarks]  with  [tag:saves] even though those tagged questions are about the old system. Surely there must be a better use of people's time than trying to replaced "bookmarked" with "saved" everywhere.

Comment: @ColleenV: In my personal opinion, the functionality of the Saves feature seems different enough from how the Bookmarks feature currently works that it'd probably make sense to keep it as a different tag, and simply edit the [bookmarks] tag wiki to clarify the distinction. But that'd be a decision this community can make for itself.

Comment: Thank you for bringing this to our attention. The new badges (Favorite and Stellar Answer) are hidden for now. This has been addressed in the separate bug reports. This was not intentional until as we were going to _save_ this for when we were ready to launch (hint: it's soon ) but we'll leave it up for now.

Comment: @tanj92 Neat-o! Thanks for the *save*! As to the bookmark icon, what was the rationale behind that change so close to the save feature launch?

Comment: @Spevacus the bookmarks icon was deployed yesterday to our design system which was an oversight on our part to not call out in the FAQ section in preparation for the launch soon, but they will be slightly different in that there will be a default state (unfilled) for when posts haven't been saved and filled when they are. This change will be made early next week. This was a mistake on our part to not properly include this in the FAQ and we apologize for the confusion.

Comment: No worries, @tanj92 , these things happen :) Thanks for staying on top of things and being the person to apologize on behalf of y'all, I know it sucks to be that person. Have a happy weekend :D

Comment: Appreciate the kind words. I'm stoked and can't wait to release this to everyone soon! You have a great weekend as well.

Comment: @V2Blast The community didn't decide to synonymize [tag:favorites] with [tag:bookmarks]. Staff did. Regardless, I don't particularly care. I'm not going to be a user of that feature, and it's certainly not going to be me that has to deal with any of the fallout from a bad name choice. I just am unable to keep my opinion to myself sometimes :)

Comment: @ColleenV: In [the case of Favorites becoming Bookmarks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/347558/335251), there was literally no change other than the name and icon, so it makes sense that staff simply renamed/synonymized the existing tag. In this case, there is actually a change in how the feature works, so I don't think it's as obvious how to handle the tag. (In any case, I'm not a decision-maker on this project; that's just my own opinion.)

Comment: @tanj92 hey, any updates on actual ETA of the launch? 

Comment: It's now been launched ;)

Answer (score 9):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [character-limit](/questions/tagged/character-limit) [spelling](/questions/tagged/spelling) [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review)

If you go to your [Saves](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/saves/current) tab and attempt to save a note longer than 500 characters, it shows this:

[image]

However, it is possible to save a note longer than 500 <strike>charaters</strike> characters by simply saving the note (in "For Later") this way:

- Click "Manage" after saving an answer.
- Write a lengthy essay into the private note space.
- Save.

If you try to edit the note at the appropriate page **after** saving the note this way, it will show the toast notification with the error, so we have inconsistency and typos going on.

---

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [character-limit](/questions/tagged/character-limit) [design](/questions/tagged/design)

Since the note is limited to 500 characters, could we also add a "Characters left" counter at the bottom as we do with comments, since it would help keep track and alert you when you're about to overfill the note space?

Comment: Thanks for the bug report! A ticket has been created for the minor typo and the ability to bypass the 500 character limit in the Manage modal/popup. Re: characters left counter I will circle back with the team on this. For now, the status-review tag is applied to the two bugs.

Answer (score 8):

I'd love to have Markdown integration with my saves.  Like if I type a snippet from the title of something I'd saved:

- `[sitemap paradox]` I'd like it to create a link to [The Sitemap Paradox](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/4803/the-sitemap-paradox)
- `[position in google]` I'd like it to create a link to [What are the best ways to improve a site's position in Google?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2/what-are-the-best-ways-to-improve-a-sites-position-in-google)

One reason I save questions is so that I can suggest them as references in comments on other questions.

Answer (score 8):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

In [SOpt](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/112052/hkotsubo) I have 252 <strike>bookmarks</strike> saved posts.

I want to move them from *For Later* to one of *My Lists*. Currently, I have two options to accomplish that:

## Option 1

- Go to my profile's Saves page
- Look for the post I want to move, which is a tedious process, as there are 9 pages of saved posts. Even using different sort options, it's not always straighforward to find it
- After finding the post in the list, I can move it using the menu:

[image: 'move to' menu]

- Repeat it for every post I want to move

## Option 2

- Go to the post's page (usually searching for `in:saves some criteria to find the post`)
- Click on the Save icon twice (once to unsave it, once to save it again, so the "Manage" link is displayed), and then click on "Manage" to move it to the desired List
- Repeat it for every post I want to move

---

Doing that for 252 posts is... not feasible. Can we have a better way to accomplish that?

Perhaps having some way to filter posts directly in the profile's Saves page, and then select them and move all at once (as suggested [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/382621/401803)).

Comment: I think this is the same FR [as this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/382621) but you posted a few hours later.

Comment: It would also be nice to be able to *clear* saved posts in bulk...  I'd generalise it to bulk management tools :D

Comment: Yes, that would be nice. I once added a special macro to my macro keyboard to help with saving off the URLs to a text document and deleting about 300 bookmarks.

Comment: My userscript [SavedPostsHelper.user.js](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/blob/master/SavedPostsHelper.user.js) adds bulk-moving checkboxes.

Answer (score 8):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

When using the keyboard to select a list item after `Move to...` (for example, pressing <kbd>s</kbd>) the drop-down list (DDL) puts the first list starting with the desired letter at the bottom of the DDL.

[image: Move to dialogue list starting with s at the bottom]

However, if I've pressed <kbd>s</kbd>, it would be convenient that the first item be placed at the top of the DDL, because I want to be looking at lists starting with `s`. (This way extra scrolling or keystrokes can be avoided.)

[image: Move to dialogue list starting with s at the bottom]

Comment: I know nothing about the code involved, but wouldn't this behavior be determined by the browser?

Comment: @V2Blast afaik SE is implemented in C# + ASP.NET + jQuery, so in [the DLL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.dropdownlist?view=netframework-4.8) after the HTML is served there should be a bind to JS allowing to customize behavior on keystroke. I don't think it's necessarily browser dependent.

Answer (score 8):

My list name clearly isn't empty, however I can't save it, because it is empty.

[image: Printscreen showing the errormessage "List name cannot be empty." while the list name is set to "‍"]

I know these characters encode to a zero-width joiner, so I'm technically a bit cheating, but either the error message isn't correct here, as one can clearly see 5 characters in the box, or this just needs to be parsed as plain text before checking on the length of the input.

Comment: That depends on the definition of 'empty', I think it is a good idea to include `&zwj;` in that definition. And while the error could be more explicit like _The list name as entered is not allowed to result in the list name as displayed to be blank_ or so, this would be unnecessarily long because it is already quite clear what the problem is.

Comment: But wouldn't this be an excellent name for a list if I want to save things about zero-width joiners. It wouldn't be that hard to parse this as just plain text, and not interpret it as anything more then that.

Comment: (The Unicode equivalent to [`&zwj;`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references#List_of_character_entity_references_in_HTML) may be [U+200D](https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=8200&number=128) (decimal 8205).)

Answer (score 8):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)[status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review)

##### The drop down lists of the "Save to" and "Move to" dialogs are presented in list ID order and not alphabetical order

After clicking the Saves button, the Saves list is presented in alphabetical order in the left hand navigation panel.

[image]

However, the list of Saves in the drop down lists of the "Save to" and "Move to" dialogs are not presented in alphabetical order. Instead, they are presented in list ID order.

[image]

To see the list ID for a particular list, click on a Saves list in the left hand navigation panel and look at the last number of the URL in the address bar. It is then trivial to compare those IDs with the list order in the drop down lists of the two dialogs.

[image]

I suspect that this may have been working correctly at some time and this bug has been introduced recently. I believe that [another answer to this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/382685) shows that these drop down lists were sorted alphabetically at some point.

[image]

This bug may be connected to this [bug report about no way to add a post to an empty Saves list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/384057).

Comment: This has been ticketed, thanks for reporting!

Comment: @tanj92 Has this now been fixed? I just noticed that the "Save to" and "Move to" dialogs now present the Saves List in alphabetical order.

Answer (score 7):

> **What happens if a post I saved has been deleted?**
>
> We will be preserving the existing behavior: If you have the [access to moderator tools](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) privilege, you will be able to see deleted posts in your saved lists. If you haven't earned this privilege yet, you will only be able to view deleted posts that you have authored.

What happens (on sites where I don't have the access to mod tools privileges) to my private notes if a post I saved has been deleted? Will I still be able to access those notes, or will they be hidden too?

Comment: AFAIK, if you don't have 10k rep and if you are not the OP of saved post, you can't see it (also, the note).

Comment: @Random Yes, I realise that the saved post itself will be hidden. I'm only asking about the private notes. I suspect they'll be lost (just like comments on deleted posts), but I'm hoping that the staff can clarify that.

Comment: @PM2Ring comments on deleted post are not lost, they are still there. Users who can see the deleted post can also see the comments.

Comment: @Shadow Yes, I realise that: I have delete privs on 3 sites. But for users without delete privs, any comments they've posted on deleted posts become hidden.

Comment: @PM2Ring I understand, wording just somewhat confusing. Guess "hidden" is correct, since it's something that exists but you can't see, so that's fine. Anyhow, like Random said, I also believe you won't be able to see your private note anymore, until you get enough reputation to see the deleted post.

Answer (score 7):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)
**Can it be made more obvious that Manage is an actual button?**

In this screenshot you see me hovering over the Manage button, only then it becomes apparent that it is in fact a button.
[image]

In this screenshot it is obvious that "For Later" is a link, and it is rather intuitive to click on an "x" to make things close, but "Manage" here is formatted pretty similar to the rest of the text in the banner, and therefore hard to distinguish as a button that does something.

Answer (score 7):

[support](/questions/tagged/support)

Community wiki posts are shown differently than they are in other lists. Is that on purpose? Most questions in Saves show the timestamp, but for community wikis, it's just "Community wiki [author]":

[image]

while that question on the [Following tab](/users/current?tab=following) shows only the timestamp of asking:

[image]

and other questions in the Saves tab do show the asking timestamp:

[image]

Answer (score 7):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

After clicking `Move to...` focus should be set on the drop down list in the next dialogue. (Currently focus is still kept on the background page.)

[image: Move too link and dialogue]

Answer (score 7):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [responsive-design](/questions/tagged/responsive-design) [mobile-safari](/questions/tagged/mobile-safari) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Managing the saves does not work in the mobile version of Safari (tested on an iPhone SE 2020 with iOS 15.7). I can open the menu on a saved item, but tapping on any of the entries (Unsave, Move to..., Add private note) has no effect.

[image]

Comment: Possibly related: *["Review your question" button not working on iOS 15](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382609/review-your-question-button-not-working-on-ios-15)*

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum: Indeed. That problem [has been fixed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/382671/196432), and it seems that that fixed this problem as well.

Answer (score 7):

There's a tooltip to notify users of this new feature. On all sites in the network, it links to https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/saves - can it please link to the site's own help center, to avoid [a lot of lost souls ending up asking off-topic questions here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/317599/295232)?

[image]

Comment: According to [this staff comment to another answer to this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382019/bookmarks-have-evolved-into-saves?page=3&tab=createdasc#comment1277039_382886), the tooltip/popover has been disabled on all sites except for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 7):

I like this feature, however, the code needs a callback when all ads have loaded, or, if the height is fixed, a wrapper around the ad. The page moves and makes it look unsightly:

[image]

Comment: I had noticed this, the problem with putting the popup lower is that it'll be placed at the middle of the screen on some resolutions which arguably doesn't give it proper emphasis. Assuming it's displayed one single time before being dismissed emphasis likely takes precedence of relative placement.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. For now, the popover has been disabled on all sites except for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 7):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

There is currently no way to check which list a saved post is in (this has already been reported in [this other answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/382624/1242908) and [this other answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/382625/1242908) to this question).

It would also be useful to have this information/functionality from the Search Results page.

For example, I was looking for a question about "comments" that I had saved with the word "comments" in the title. So, I searched for "in:saves comments".

[image]

Instead of the list of posts displayed in the current Search Results page which gives me no idea in which Saves list the relevant post was saved, I suggest something like below (which is similar to the view displayed when clicking the "All saves" button on the Saves page.

[image]

##### Suggested improvements

Please add information about which Saves list a post is saved in to the Search Results page.

In addition, it would also be useful to add the three vertical dots menu button with relevant actions.

Comment: related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/382624/997587

Answer (score 6):

[support](/questions/tagged/support)

What will happen to the timeline of old questions after bookmarks evolve into Saves?

Let's take a look at one of my old [questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/377087)' [timeline](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/377087/timeline?filter=WithVoteSummaries) (with vote summaries):

[image]

Will the word "Bookmark" under ***comment*** column change to "Saves" for questions which were posted before the announcement of Saves?

Also, how will the timeline look (w.r.t. Saves feature) for new questions after Saves feature gets implemented?

Since Saves is also applicable to answers, how will the timeline of answers look like (w.r.t. Saves feature)? Will it be similar to that of timeline of new questions?

Comment: Looks like it's completely removed from the timeline. And the action of saving a post also doesn't add new entries to the timeline. It's still best to get an official answer from staff to confirm that this is the intended behavior though.

Answer (score 6):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) Manage (add, remove, rename, [default](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/382575/319265), [public](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/382569/319265)) lists on network profile, to be inherited on all sites.

I expect to want the same kinds of lists (For later, Reference, etc.) on all SE sites. It looks like I'll have to set them up on each site profile individually. Then I'll have to remember to do that whenever I join another site.

I'd rather set them once and maybe be able to override them on any one site. The network profile already provides an inheritance system for profile info, so perhaps it could do the same for list preferences.

Answer (score 6):

[support](/questions/tagged/support)

Can staff members really not see the Saves of a user?

[tanj92](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/1172320/tanj92) said this in [their comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/1274231):

> @RandomPerson regarding your question re: whether staff can see saved posts for all users, the short answer is no, not from the new user interface. Only users who are logged into their own accounts can view their saved posts.

Does this really mean that no one other than the user can see the user's Saves? Or can a staff member with moderator privilege see the Saves of a user?

Also what do you exactly mean by "*not from the new user interface*"? I have no idea of which interface you're talking about. So, if a new interface is built, can staff members see the Saves of a user?

Comment: Staff members with database access can (obviously) see your saves. That information is not end-to-end encrypted (and why should it?) They just can't see it while visiting the site, while e.g. they *are* able to see individual votes.

Comment: Sounds to me like there is currently (and in the future) no interface that would show you the saves of another user, regardless of your privileges (user, moderator, staff). Of course there's probably staff with the privilege to impersonate users, and there's database admins, but "normal" support staff will not be able to access anyone's saves.

Comment: What @Glorfindel said is correct. We can still access them from the database (e.g. SEDE) but if I were to navigate to someone's profile today, I wouldn't be able to see them even if I had mod privileges.

Comment: @Bergi "impersonate users"? What do you mean?

Comment: @tanj92 Can appointed moderators (example: Glorfindel) access a user's Saves using SEDE? Can non-moderators (example: me) access other user's Saves using SEDE?

Comment: @RandomPerson by SEDE, I believe it's SE's own internal SEDE, not the public SEDE.

Answer (score 6):

Currently, there seems to be no link from the page of a saved post to where I can edit its private notes, "Move to..." another list, etc.

**Suggested improvement**

Please change what is currently the "unsave" action (clicking the active bookmark icon again) to the same as the "Manage" button on the toast message instead of "unsaving" right away.

Then, inside the "Manage" popup dialog, please add a "Delete" or "Unsave" button. I may want to go back after saving a post and add a private note, and I should be able to do so directly from the post page.

This suggested improvement would be similar to how the bookmark button works in browsers such as Firefox, for example. Clicking the star in Firefox again shows the options for that save, and you can remove the favorite from there or edit it.

Comment: Exactly! I think everyone will run into this at some point.

Answer (score 6):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

Could you make the toast messages more explicit with list names<sup>1</sup> (e.g., double quotations, etc.) to avoid miscommunication? I would prefer to see something like:

> The "List name" list has been deleted [from your lists].

instead of:

> - Styling has been deleted from your lists.
> - this has been deleted from your lists.<sup>2</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>This should apply to all toast messages that include the name of a list.</sub>

<sup>2</sup> <sub>`this` is a keyword in several programming languages, so it's not unlikely that someone might have a list named "this".</sub>

Answer (score 6):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)

The Saves icon (of a Saved post) is not highlighted on the **Review tasks page** of a reviewed task

While working through the review queues, I regularly add posts to my Saves lists. Every now and then, I review my progress by clicking on the **History page** for a review queue. I then click on the link in the Action column (Looks OK, Share Feedback, etc.) to display the **Review summary page** for the reviewed task.

Today, I reviewed a post in this way that I was sure I had already saved. But there was no highlight, so I clicked on the Saves icon again. A "Save this question" tooltip appeared next to the Saves icon and "An error occurred" message appeared at the top of the screen.

On further investigation, it turns out that I had indeed saved this post before, but this information (i.e. the highlit Saves icon) was not being displayed on the **Review summary page**.

To reproduce this effect:

1. display a review queue (for example, the First questions queue on Stack Overflow)
2. click History to display the history page
3. click on a post title link in the Task column to display a post
4. add the post to a Saves list by clicking the Saves icon
5. return to the History page
6. click on the relevant action link in the Action column
7. the Saves icon will be gray whereas the Saves icon will be highlit on the post page

[image]
If there were an answer which had been added to a Saves list, then clicking on the Answers tab from the **Review summary page** would also show that the Saves icon of that answer was not highlighted.

Please note that if the post had not been previously Saved to a Saves list, then it is possible to add/remove the post to/from a Saves list, which I presume is the expected behavior.

###### Vote icons are also not highlit

As an aside, if I had cast a vote during the review process then the vote icons are also not highlit (see green circles on first image) but I have not investigated this further.

This was tested on the first four review queues of [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/)

Comment: Hello, based on my [recent comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382019/bookmarks-have-evolved-into-saves/383254#comment1279516_383185) in another bug report, the Saves button has been disabled from Review Queues. As such, I will be adding the status-declined tag.

Answer (score 6):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)

The "New list" input box does not appear after selecting "Create new list" on the new "Save to" dialog in at least one situation, as described below.

---

1. select "Triage" from the REVIEW QUEUES drop down menu on the top bar on ([Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/))
2. click "History"
3. click on an action in the Action column (Looks OK, Flag, etc.) of a post which has not already be added to any Saves list
4. click on the "Saves" icon (which turns orange for me on SO)
5. click on "Manage" in the toast message which appears at the top of the screen
6. click on "For later" in the drop down list box and select "Create new list" from the bottom of the list box
7. the input box with the "New list" placeholder text **does not appear**
8. click on "Done" and a toast error message appears: "List name cannot be empty."

This was tested on the first four review queues of [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/).

Only the **Triage Review Queue** demonstrated this behavior.

[image]

Comment: The same issue exists for Chemistry SE so it's not a site issue. Thanks for bringing it up

Comment: Hello, we recently discovered that the Saves icon was inherited on the review queues. Previously, with bookmarks, it was intentionally hidden. Given that bookmarks were not enabled before, we have decided to remove the Saves icon from review queues. As such, I've updated the tag to status-declined.

Answer (score 5):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

> but the sorting fun doesn't end there.

The **"MY LISTS"** shown on the left should be easily **sortable**.

Currently other lists, like ["Custom Filters"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/353830/how-to-swap-order-of-custom-filters), are sorted alphabetically by default and can't be sorted in any other way (you have to rename the filters if you want a different order). The same goes for the ["Hidden Communities List"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/291708) in the user profile page; it keeps the order of insertion for the sites you have an account in (meaning you have to add and remove sites from the hidden list to force a different sort order).

I think it would be an important feature that the new **"MY LISTS"** listing have some sort of drag and drop sorting. Or at least something (like clickable arrows for example) that allows to easily change the order of items in the list.

Comment: Are you thinking exclusively of custom sorting or of easier options like bookmark date, last edited date, or post creation date?

Comment: @TylerH I'd be happy if "MY LISTS" just allowed the user to sort the items manually. (It would be better than no sorting option, or how sorting hidden communities works atm.)

Comment: I wonder how sorting would be stored for custom sorts; either new database tables or cookies. The former seems expensive and the latter seems... clunky and impermanent.

Comment: @TylerH new column in the SavedLists table, with a number implying the list position in the custom sort.

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard So, potentially infinitely more columns in that table? One for each custom sort each user creates? That doesn't scale well.

Comment: @TylerH no. Each row in the table is one custom list. There will be one single additional column used for the sort. Note, I'm talking in theory only, based on how I'd implement it, it might be totally different in SE code.

Answer (score 5):

I think the vertical space between saved posts is too much and the design could be slightly more compact. If you add notes the empty vertical space becomes even more apparent, see the highlighted sections in the screenshot:

[image: two saved posts with a note]

Answer (score 5):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Users without access to moderator tools privilege are not able to view deleted posts that they have authored in their saved lists

With reference to:

> **What happens if a post I saved has been deleted?**
>
> We will be preserving the existing behavior: If you have the [access to moderator tools](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) privilege, you will be able to see deleted posts in your saved lists. If you haven't earned this privilege yet, you will only be able to view deleted posts that you have authored.

However, I do not have the **access to moderator tools** privilege and I cannot view deleted posts that I have authored in my saved lists.

The following screenshot shows that I have two posts "Saved" to my "To review" list. One of them is a highly voted question (with a simple private note added) and the other is my own deleted answer (to another question).

[image]

Under the list title the phrase "1 saved item" appears and there is only one saved item in the list (the highly voted question). In the "Move to" dialog, the item text states "To review (2)" proving that my deleted post is present in the list but not visible to me.

This was only tested on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) with deleted answer posts.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Assuming you are a user without the access to moderator tools privilege
2. Create a saved list, e.g. "To review"
3. Add any (not deleted) question or answer to this "To review" saved list
4. Add any deleted answer of yours to this "To review" saved list (deleted answers can be accessed by scrolling down to the bottom of the Answers tab)
5. Click on the Saves button and click on "To review" in MY LISTS
6. Click on the three vertical dots menu button located at the top right of an item in the list
7. Click on "Move to..."
8. The number of saved items under the "To review" list title on the underlying page will be less than the number in brackets in the dialog next the "To review" list title

Comment: A fix has been deployed. Please let us know if you're still experiencing issues. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

Make handling of links to deleted posts consistent with that of [follow-post](/questions/tagged/follow-post) feature.

---

From end user perspective Saves and Follow-post are much similar because both features provide a way for users to create and edit lists of links to posts.

One noticeable difference is in the way how these lists handle links to deleted posts: Saves automatically delete such links (I would expect that this is complemented by automatic recovery in case of undeletion) while Follow-post list keeps such links and just provides users an option to remove them manually.

For smoother user experience suggest that both features use the same way of handling links to deleted posts. For this, one of them should change its current way to one used in another.

---

At the moment I don't have strong reasons to tell which of two ways is better. My personal preference goes to the way how it is done in Follow-post feature, primarily because it looks less likely to interfere with auto-deletion scripts, as discussed eg in this bug report at MSO: [Roomba hasn't run for the past two weeks and over 2800 questions evaded it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/420707/839601).

Comment: I'd say that the correct answer is that should not remove links to deleted posts.  You can save deleted posts; why should you only be able to do so if they're already deleted?

Answer (score 4):

> Stack Overflow was the only site partially migrated

Does this mean it takes a seriously long time to migrate all bookmarks to saves? I understand there are over 180 sites and surely millions of bookmarks, but why does it take such a long time to migrate?

You could view my question as: is the long amount of time it requires to change due to the duplications of the new tables, lists, queries, etc. for bookmarks -> saves?

Comment: Simply there are few greater horrors than need to batch process data in bulk.

Comment: It does take a long time. Take a look at when [Reddit banned half of a subreddit](https://www.twitch.tv/videos/282773443?t=41m04s), which was around 300k users. For comparison, we moved more than 14 million bookmarks from `Posts2Votes` into a new table for Saves.

Answer (score 4):

### After migration from Bookmarks to Saves, neither is now available on stackexchange.com anymore

Pic attached refers. In the area marked in red I used to be able to access bookmarks from *all* of my accounts.

This was especially handy when I needed to lookup a bookmark but I couldn't remember on which account (some topics may fit multiple SEs in some cases).

Now that ability seems gone.

Has it been moved somewhere else, is it temporarily disabled or has it been killed altogether?

[image: bookmarks and saves gone]

Comment: It is explicitly mentioned under the last FAQ of the announcement that this tab will not be available on the network profile for now.

Comment: @animuson why roll out a feature if it's half-baked? The aggregation was the entire reason I used bookmarks. I relied on it. I'll now have to go to each SE site one-by-one to migrate them elsewhere. Also, "for now." Your comment is over a year old, and aggregation is still unavailable.

Answer (score 4):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

Bountied answers look cluttered because of the Saves button.

[image]

Can you please increase the spacing between Saves button and bounty awarded label?

Answer (score 4):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)

It is possible to save a post to two "Saves lists" in at least one way, as described below.

In your question, you state:

> ###### Can I save a post to multiple lists?
>
> Currently, we are only allowing a post to be saved to a single list.

However, the following demonstrates otherwise:

1. select "Triage" from the REVIEW QUEUES drop down menu on the top bar on (Stack Overflow)
2. click "History"
3. click on an action in the Action column (Looks OK, Flag, etc.) of a post which has not already be added to any Saves list
4. click on the "Saves" icon (which turns orange for me on SO)
5. return to your profile page and click on the "Saves" tab button
6. click on "All saves" and "Added" and the post will be listed **twice** in the "For later" list
7. to move to a different list, click on the three dots menu for one of the duplicated posts and click on "Move to"
8. select a different list (say, "Triage") and click "Done"

[image]

9. the post will **appear** to be listed in the "Triage" list **twice**

[image]

10. However, click on the "All saves" button and the page will refresh and now the post will be in two lists.

[image]

I have not exhaustively investigated this further, but it appears that "Unsaving" a duplicated post removes both entries from both lists.

This bug may or may not be connected to another [bug reported here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/383185) — please note that the first four steps are identical.

This was tested on the first four review queues of [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/).

Only the **Triage Review Queue** demonstrated this behavior.

Comment: Able to replicate.

Comment: Hello, based on my [recent comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382019/bookmarks-have-evolved-into-saves/383254#comment1279516_383185) in another bug report, the Saves button has been disabled from Review Queues. As such, I will be adding the status-declined tag.

Answer (score 4):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)[status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review)

#### The "Move to" dropdown includes the list where the post currently resides

This happens when browsing saved posts under "All saves":

[image]

...and even when browsing posts in that particular list:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for reporting! This has been ticketed for review.

Answer (score 4):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

#### Moving a post to a *new* list does not remove it from the current list until the page is refreshed

When browsing posts saved to a certain list and then clicking "Move to" to move it to another *existing* list, the post element gets immediately removed from the DOM. This is the expected behavior.

However, if the post is moved to a *new* list (i.e., "Move to" > "Create new list"), the post gets moved in the backend but remains displayed in the current list until the page is refreshed.

Comment: Thanks for reporting! This has been ticketed for review.

Comment: A fix has been deployed. Please let us know if you're still experiencing issues. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Will we be able to see our deleted list? I can see that deletion can be undone if I am quick enough, but if I change my mind about the deletion later, can I still undelete it?

Unrelated but, editing deleted list results in error 500. It's not a very good UX and I hope you will adjust it.

Comment: I don't think we should be testing the feature just yet, it's not published/ready.

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard Hence why I am not listing bugs yet, just suggestions on how to improve it.

Comment: Sure, my point is better wait before we access a page we should not access yet, even if for a good cause, because for all we know, they might change it drastically.

Comment: (The main bug here, which annoys me, is they still let us access those pages, without officially saying "OK, it's ready for your testing, go ahead")

Answer (score 3):

[support](/questions/tagged/support) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

The quarter has ended (July to September) and I cannot see Saves in my profile yet.

So, when are bookmarks evolving into Saves?

Comment: No worry, I've seen bugs where dev said "We're going to fix it this weekend!1!!" and it was fixed, well, a weekend 3-4 years later. So few weeks are really good so far.

Comment: Seriously though, SE just stopped posting their plans (aka "roadmaps"), the one for Q4 of 2021 was the last, so it's "We ship when it's ready, we don't know when" again like it was before.

Comment: I'm pleased to announce that Saves is officially live on Stack Overflow and across the network sites. I will create a community post to organize the bugs and feature requests soon. Thank you for your patience. Additionally, existing bookmarks will be migrated over and that will take some time to process as there are millions to process.

Answer (score 3):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

I created a save list called `exception` as shown in the screenshot:

[image: saves in user profile]

But if I try saving a post to it directly from the question the `exception` list isn't available:

[image: saving a question]

Comment: [Already reported](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/384057/152859) and under review. No need to re-post.

Answer (score 3):

[support](/questions/tagged/support)

When I use `in:saves` does it search only in the saved post - or in the other associated questions and answers.

For example:

- If I saved an answer, and I combine `in:saves` [with a tag - which is on the corresponding question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=in%3Asaves+%5Bdata-explorer%5D), will the answer be among the results? (Well, this one was easy to test and the answer is **Yes.** Moreover, this is behavior consistent with the way search works with answer in general - the tags on questions are taken into account. So I'd say that this is the expected behavior.)
- If I saved an answer and I use a `in:saves` together with a keyword which is contained in the question (but not in the answer), will the answer be among the results?
- If I saved a question and I use a keyword which is in one of the answer - will the question be among the results?

---

I am asking this as [support](/questions/tagged/support) rather than [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request). I basically just want to find how it actually works - and I am not really sure which of the possibilities would be better.

I am pretty sure that I could find out this by myself by trying a few experiments - but some other users might wonder about the same thing, so it might be good to have some kind of "official" answer.

If this would be better as a separate question, let me know - I can delete this and repost.

Comment: The in:saves operator only works on the the posts you've saved.

Answer (score 2):

[support](/questions/tagged/support)

When we un-Save a post, [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cwuoV.png) [is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/04npD.png) shown:

> Question removed from saves.

or

> Answer removed from saves.

Should it be "saves" or "Saves" (with a capital 's')?

Comment: Great question, as usual it's not consistent even in the announcement itself. Sometimes the author use "Saves", and sometimes "saves". Pity, because it indicates on a serious core problem: not paying attention to small details. And great things, as too many forget, are built from small things. This must be changed inside SO, or things will keep falling apart. :(

Comment: At a glance, it seems pretty consistent to me, with maybe 1 exception. When "Saves" is capitalized in the announcement (aside from at the start of a sentence), it's used to refer to the Saves feature itself (e.g. "An overview of the new features you'll see with Saves"). Otherwise, it's in all lowercase when used to refer to a post that you have saved (e.g. "migrating existing bookmarks into saves").

Answer (score 2):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

After selection of a list in the *Move to* dialogue, the focus should be changed to the <kbd>Done</kbd> button. Otherwise, for every save, an extra click or <kbd>Tab</kbd> is required which makes the process additionally tedious if you're organizing a large number of saves.

[image]

Comment: This would be problematic for keyboard-only users, as once they use an arrow key to select the next option, they'd have to constantly Shift+Tab back to the dropdown menu to go next.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog that's not what I'm saying, a menu item is selected after hitting Enter not moving up and down the list. What you're saying is nonsensical that pressing up or down selects the item (DDLs don't work that way).

Comment: If you press the arrow keys while there's focus on the dropdown without pressing space to open it and instead navigate it with arrow keys, the system will think you've selected the option you've changed to and act accordingly. See [this bug report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/374388/377214), starting with *This also presents a problem for keyboard-only users*.

Answer (score 2):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)[status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)

Why is Saves pop up shown to users who are not logged in?

Screenshot from Incognito mode:

[image]

Comment: Hello, this is by-design. The Saves popover will only displayed for a short period of time to promote awareness of the new feature. It will be hidden once the promotional period is over.

Comment: @tanj92 Thanks for the explanation. I just wanted to ask you this: Is there any valid reason for it to be status-bydesign? Non-logged in users cannot save posts... so I kinda feel it's not needed to show this popup to such users.

Comment: The popover is used to promote a new feature to the largest audience which is anonymous users who aren't logged in. We will be analyzing any sign ups that are attributed to this feature to determine if we're seeing more users who sign up because they want to save and organize content.

Answer (score 2):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

**Allow filters by tag(s)**

I would say this is a *good-to-have* feature.

Once the number of saved posts (questions/answers) exceeds a certain number, we would have to go through each page and search by tag on the page. If we had an option to filter by tag(s), it would enable easy filtering.

Comment: That's already possible using the `in:saves` search operator, adding a tag. e.g. [filter your Saves by the tag "fun"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=in%3Asaves+%5Bfun%5D).

Comment: @ShadowWizardChasingStars I don't think it is possible to filter by a tag on a list

Comment: You didn't read my comment lol. Please read it and you'll understand. I never said there is filter by tag on a list because it does not exist. I gave alternative solution, to do exactly the same thing with something that does exist, namely the site search.

Comment: @ShadowWizardChasingStars Wouldn't `in:saves` search through *all* saves, not just a particular list?

Comment: @Bergi yes, that is correct. The answer here does not mention anything about lists, just general filtering of the Saves so like I said, what I suggested gives exactly that.

Answer (score 0):

How do I see all my "saves" across SE without going to each site one-by-one?
I don't know if I saved this-and-that post in English or Writing, or if I saved in on SU or SO.
That was the main appeal of bookmarks.
They were aggregated in a common place.

As far as I can tell, you did not make bookmarks "more useful and robust."
You castrated them and are pretending it was an upgrade.

If it ain't broke don't fix it.

Comment: Related: [I can't search for my Saves in stackexchange.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/390435/i-cant-search-for-my-saves-in-stackexchange-com)

Answer (score -1):

[support](/questions/tagged/support)

I just noticed the saved mark is blue on MSE. Shouldn't it also be yellow?

[image: blue save under vote score]

Comment: No. It's the same color as the vote arrows, which is fine.

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard that's your opinion, it was yellow before -unless I'm mistaken- and I prefer the color, so it's not fine.

Comment: Each and their own taste, sure. I prefer it being consistent, and it was yellow before only because it was originally a star, which is yellow.

Comment: i mean... are all stars yellow?

Comment: @KevinB: Sounds like a good question to ask on [Physics.SE]. (...I mean, it's probably a bit too basic, but you know... :P)

Comment: might already be asked on space exploration :D

Comment: Now the colour has been changed based on the theme of the respective site. It's dark orange in Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @RandomPerson makes sense, apparently sites without theme have it in dark green..?!

Comment: @bad_coder Which site has it in dark green? In Literature, it looked blue.

Comment: @RandomPerson you're right it's a *"greenish"* blue...

Comment: @bad_coder I'm not sure if it's greenish. I am not good with colour names. I would call it dark blue.

Answer (score -3):

I noticed some redundancy in the "Saves" 'new list creation' command, there's two *buttons* on the same page that open the create 'New list' popup:

[image: Saves webpage, showing New List popup.]

1. Perhaps it would be better if the blue "+" on the left was replaced with a number, showing the total number of lists.

   Another alternative would be to show your top ten lists, possibly with MRU under that, there's plenty of whitespace on the left to accommodate this.
2. The "New list" popup doesn't look like it searches and displays your existing lists, so you can either avoid similar naming ***or*** copy and modify existing names to avoid some typing.

The "Feedback" offered in this answer is no so much a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request), it's to comment that the "Saves" webpage isn't  at all [fully baked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382102/able-to-access-the-saves-page#comment1274495_382102) (as has already [been acknowledged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382102/able-to-access-the-saves-page#comment1274509_382102)), and that unlike raw cookie dough, raw cake isn't very good - your inviting a bunch of bug reports or feature requests that a better baker could avoid.

I thought we'd moved towards more thorough testing, hopefully this will be the case now.

Comment: @sha, I'm not asking for a bug to be fixed, I'm asking for it to be a great UX when it goes live; a subject **you** frequently bring up, so I don't understand the opposition to this; nor am I curious.

Comment: After second read, I understand that, sorry.

Comment: It took me some time to understand the baker analogy and its good humor. I've grown weary of criticism on the board, precisely because of [the design changes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/375081) that caused so much disagreement. I actually think design issues themselves are less disruptive than the disagreement they cause.

Answer (score -6):

In terms of why the feature was renamed from Bookmarks to Saves — It was done in part because "save" is a bit more explicit than "bookmark" in terms of what the feature does. Bookmark is a great term for ebooks and browsers. When it comes to content consumption we wanted to make a clear distinction from what you would see with a browser's bookmark feature. "Bookmark a question" has a double meaning; do we mean bookmark the tab or the question itself?

I think that [Shadow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/152859/shadow-the-kid-wizard) sums it up really nicely in [his comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382019/bookmarks-are-evolving-into-saves/382035#comment1274161_382019) that at first glance, "saves" may seem too vague, but that these updates are actually something much bigger than some minor tweaks to bookmarks.

Comment: Just a quick question - why not "saved" as opposed to "saves"? I presume it was used in the technial sense of "saving data to a storage location" (for other readers - yes, this is a real term), but it's a bit too jargon-y to be easily parseable by general audience. [basically the same question that ColleenV's answer postulates]

Comment: That’s what I suspected, but “save” does not actually describe this feature better than “bookmark”. A bookmark is a saved link. The new part of this feature is more organizing bookmarks than changing the bookmarks themselves. Even something like “Folio” would be less confusing than “save” as a noun.

Comment: `Collections` would be a good name, but probably too similar to these collectives thingies,

Comment: @ColleenV that's the point, with Saves now, you can save multiple things from the same page (as answers can be saved too), it's not about bookmarking links, it's about saving content of interest into lists.

Comment: @SCoSO  It doesn't actually save the content though. It saves a link to the content. Or is it really going to create a copy of the content of the answer/question? Bookmarks are not just links to web pages in common usage. It's also pretty common for them to refer to jumping around within a web page. I empathize with the desire to name it something different, and I know naming stuff is hard, but "Saves" is not a good name for this feature, especially in a global community where many people's first language isn't English.

Comment: Looking again at the screenshot, why did y'all use "3 Saved Items" instead of just "3 Saves" when describing the list? It's setting up inconsistent language that is going to be confusing. I really think there's a better term out there if "bookmark" is completely unusable for whatever reason.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz We also already use Collections as a feature name within Teams. ;)

Comment: Bookmarks as a term were a thing before the internet, I don't think it is a huge issue that the SE bookmarks work a bit differently than browser bookmarks. I still think bookmarks are the better name for this.

Comment: @MadScientist well, I think we can't change the decision now, however after the change is live, it would be legit to start feature request asking to  change the name again. With enough people supporting it, and more important, well explained reasons, they might reconsider. It happened before that they reverted a change only after pushing it, due to popular demand.

Comment: You can make a big improvement to something without having to invent a completely new name for it. [3D Connexion](https://3dconnexion.com/us/) still keeps “mouse’ in their product name. It actually helps people understand what it does as opposed to calling it a “puck” or something.

Comment: *"do we mean bookmark the tab or the question itself?"* What? What does this distinction even mean? How would a feature on a website bookmark a tab? I don't know if you're trying to say that instead of bookmarking a URL/URI, you're bookmarking a question, but even that doesn't matter, because we don't ever move questions to a new URI, so there is no distinction. (Unless perhaps if a question gets merged or migrated, but it still redirects. What'll the "save" do?) There is nothing at all explicit about "save" compared to "bookmark". Save is a verb. Talk about a double meaning.

Comment: "*we wanted to make a clear distinction from what you would see with a browser's bookmark feature*" - uh, what exactly **is** that distinction? As far as I can tell, it works exactly like my browser's bookmarking feature: I can add and remove links to online content to/from lists (folders) and add comments/descriptions on the entries.