# "favorite answer" badges and new descriptions for "favorite question" badges have already been deployed

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges, bookmarks

As part of the [bookmarks being turned into "saves" change](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/382019/294691), the badges associated with bookmarked questions are being updated to reflect the rename, as well as new badges being added for saved answers. The "saves" features have not been released yet, though.

However, as noted in [chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/9301761), the wording for the "Favorite Question" badges has already been changed, and the new answer versions of these badges are already live in the badges page:

[image: A silver badge named "Favorite Answer" and a gold badge named "Stellar Answer" in the badge list. Neither badge has been earned by anyone.]

Since the saves feature changes have not yet been implemented, the badges probably shouldn't be updated or live until the saves feature is actually released. It's just liable to cause confusion by being changed early.

Comment: Related bug report aka another major leakage: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382102/able-to-access-the-saves-page.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for bringing this to our attention. This was a mistake on our part while we were conducting internal testing. The new Favorite Answer and Stellar Answer badges have been hidden for now.

The badge descriptions for Favorite Question and Favorite Answer still show the “saved” wording due to them being cached. We apologize for any confusion caused. When we are ready to launch, we will communicate and update the original Meta post.

I've updated the status to [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed).

Comment: I am really curious, how can "internal testing" cause changes in production? Are those two environments not totally separate? Unless you perform tests on production, which IMHO is pretty bad practice, but hey, that's off topic here.

Comment: The environments are separate. Features are tested in a dev environment before they are deployed to production. Once deployed, they can be tied behind a site setting until they are ready for launch. We had several site settings for this feature. When we enabled one of them for internal testing, it made certain changes visible on the site.

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard I don't know whether it's helpful but we have two ways to test things "internally" - we can test on our dev environment, which requires access to the dev site or we can ship things to public but only make them available/visible to certain user types - or even specific user IDs. It gives us a chance to see the integrations on the live site. It's how we test Winter Bash every year. It's similar to how mods only have mod tools and devs only have access to certain dev pages... there's even CM-specific pages.