# Able to access the "Saves" page

Tags: bug, status-completed, saves

[Bookmarks Are Evolving Into Saves](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/382019/312043) is not yet published.
But when I tried to hit the URL `https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/saves/<userid>`, the **saves** page is opening and I'm able to add a few lists to my profile too.

Before the full functionality was published, able to use partial features.

[image: Saves page]

Comment: Although the standard `current` in place of the user ID doesn't seem to work (yet).

Comment: ... and trying the userid of someone else gives a nice json error response.

Comment: Related: [an answer to *Bookmarks Are Evolving Into Saves*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382019/bookmarks-are-evolving-into-saves/382100#382100).

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum FWIW I've edited a link to this answer into my answer there because it's less about "Here are some exposed problems, could they be fixed?" and more about "Hey, some of your commits are leaking to production when they look like they're not supposed to be. Can you review them?"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Thanks for bringing this to our attention. We were conducting rounds of internal testing this week and enabling the feature resulted in the URL being live for those who were able to directly access the page. This was not intentional until as we were going to *save* this for when we were ready to launch (hint: it's soon ) but we'll leave it up for now.

I'm impressed Meta was able to find the URL this quick but we'll do better next time .

I will be updating the status to [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned). Once we launch, I will change it to [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed).

Comment: So you really don't have test/dev environment, if you do internal testing out in the open.

Comment: We have dev environments for testing which we conducted on, but we wanted to perform testing on production behind a site setting to address any issues that we may not have seen in a dev environment. The URL was accessible but wasn't exposed on profile pages.

Comment: OK, not ideal, but why didn't you disable the access once test was done? Also, the [tag:status-completed] tag here is wrong, if you leave this working, it means the reject the bug, or saying it's by design. Nitpicking, I know,  but... Meta. :-)

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard We were still conducting testing for a few more items. I've updated the tag to status-planned. Once we launch, I will change it to status-completed. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: I mean, the bug is simple: we can access a page that we should not be able to access yet. As long as we can still access it, the bug isn't "fixed". When launched and we will have access as planned, the bug will become "by design", as this is how the system should actually behave.

Comment: Anyhow, I did learn a lot about your internal working from this "mini ordeal", so thanks for sharing and explaining.