# Can we have a little whitespace between lines in user cards?

Tags: bug, design, user-card, whitespace, user-labels

I just noticed the usercard of our Community Manager [Salmon_of_Wisdom](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/1081359/salmon-of-wisdom) in this [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382019/bookmarks-are-evolving-into-saves), where they made an edit (which was superseded by another edit, yes one by me):

[image]

As their username is relatively long, and they have two labels next to their name, a staff and a moderator one. Because the space in a usercard is limited, even with a wide screen monitor like mine, a part of their name has to wrap into a new line. Which in this case is the labels.

The problem now is that the underscores in their username sit flush against the labels, a few pixels spacing would be better.

The offending piece of CSS is this:

```css
.mtn4 {
  margin-top: calc(var(--su4) * -1) !important;
```

Disabling that gives a few pixels of spacing between Salmon_of_Wisdom's name and their labels, however it also messes up the alignment of the staff label of tanj92 in this case:

[image]

tanj92's staff label now sits a bit lower then their username.

Comment: ...which could be fixed by shifting the padding _inside_ the staff / mod labels (+1px above, -1px below), but then that would mess up {some other thing}, and fixing that would then mess up {yet another thing}, ad nauseum... CSS is a blessing and a curse.

Comment: @AaronBertrand that's usually true indeed. But I know SE employs people way more skilled with CSS then myself, so I'll let them mess with it for a while ;)

Comment: Arguably, the change you propose actually fixes the alignment issue that exists for the "Staff" badge in tanj92's usercard. IMO, it's better to have the text align vertically. It appears that they are attempting to center the entire badge within the line, which is a reasonable alternate treatment, assuming they are wanting to keep the same amount of padding in the badge (which currently is 1 px more on the bottom than the top, at least in Firefox). As has been mentioned, there are a lot of trade-offs which are made with alignment in CSS. It's often that you just have to make a judgement call.

Comment: BTW: it would be good if you mention that the question to which you link as an example no longer exhibits the issue you're reporting, particularly given that it was your edit to that question which eliminated it as an active example. Mentioning that would prevent people trying to go to that question to see the issue for themselves.

Comment: @Makyen good point, sometimes you don't think twice. xD

Comment: Some disruptive content-shifting when you expand the "extra" user cards now, too, when there are comments: the comments shift down (because the text inside the static user card shifts down, making that element taller). It's hard to screenshot due to timing, just hover over the OP's avatar to see it in action.