# "An error occurred" when double-clicking on the new "Saves" icon

Tags: bug, status-completed, error-message, saves

With reference to: [Bookmarks have evolved into Saves](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/382019/1242908)

Double-clicking on the new Saves icon (below the Downvote arrow) displays the **An error occurred** message approximately 10-20 percent of the time (presumably depends on factors such as double-click speed, quality of internet connection, mouse movement, etc.)

> [image: An error occurred]

It is reproducible. However, to display the error message it may be necessary to double-click quickly multiple times in a row.

I tested this on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com) and [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com)

I expected a "Saves Manager Dialog" to appear when I double-clicked the Saves icon, however this has not been implemented.

Comment: Why a normal user will do such a thing? I see no reason.

Comment: I am a normal user. If I see "An error occurred" message, I feel I should report it. I noticed it the very first time I used the feature with just one double-click. The above report about multiple double-clicking is to demonstrate how to reproduce it.

Comment: Sure, but to Save a post one click is enough. Clicking it 10-20 times on purpose is trying to make a bug on purpose. Of course, ideally it can be fixed by disabling the button while the request is pending, but what I'm saying is that it's very low impact.

Comment: My use case was different. I saved a post and then I wanted to move it to another list. However, clicking on the Saves icon simply unsaved it -- which is obviously the correct behavior. So, I tried to double-click it. And I saw the error message. I am sure it is low impact.

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard Sometimes my mouse registers two clicks when I click once. If that happens when clicking the button and the error message comes up, it's extremely confusing.

Comment: Most likely the same root cause of [this bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/382623/348196).

Comment: A lot of normal users, incl. highly trained [Ph.D.s](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doctor_of_Philosophy), double-click on things in a web browser, even many years later. Presumably, it is a skill transferred from using desktop GUIs. (Informal) [usability testing](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2000/08/09/the-joel-test-12-steps-to-better-code/) lets you see such things firsthand.

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum I fail to see how the Joel Test got anything to do with clicking several times in a row on things. It was good blast from the past to read it, but it's not related here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this issue! This is caused by a race condition where a user attempts to save a post that's already saved, or unsave a post that's not saved.

The issue happens when someone clicks on the button really fast more than once, but the backend hasn't properly processed the first click yet.

For now, we made some front-end and back-end improvement. This issue shouldn't happen anymore if a user double clicks on the button.