# Error after saving and unsaving several times

Tags: bug, saves

On [some SE question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/24933/1810), after several save's/unsave's, I arrived at some state where I couldn't save the question anymore, until refreshing the page.

Here is what happens:

[image: GIF image showing the problem]

My network was fine. Chrome version 108.0.5359.125 (Official Build) (64-bit) on Windows 10.

Comment: I am confirming that I have seen this error as well (on Stack Overflow). Not sure how to reproduce, but it certainly happens sporadically. (Chrome 108.0.5359.124, macOS Ventura 13.1)

Comment: Very related: ["An error occurred" when double-clicking on the new "Saves" icon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382633/an-error-occurred-when-double-clicking-on-the-new-saves-icon)

Comment: @ShadowWizardChasingStars hmm I may have double-clicked indeed, my dwell clicking software is rather trigger-happy.

Comment: Well there is a way to reproduce without several clicks. 1) Save the question, 2) Go to a different page, 3) Click back in the browser 4) Try to save again. (The save icon isn't highlighted)

Comment: @ShadowWizardChasingStars got it, I believe to have done a click back in the browser too (the dwell clicking software clicked on some links I didn't want to follow)

Comment: @ShadowWizardChasingStars: A similar bug was also reported in [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/382623/335251) to the Saves announcement.

Comment: @V2Blast yes, that's the same issue. Think we should close this as duplicate then? Is the announcement thread still monitored?

Comment: Not sure – I think there's an internal ticket for that issue, but I'll follow up and see how they want to handle it. (For now, I'll leave it up to the community to handle as y'all see fit.)