# API request for "favorites" now returning an empty list – is there a way to get something equivalent for saves?

Tags: support, status-review, bookmarks, api, saves

I have a script which I use, based on the StackExchange API, to regularly download a local backup of various questions relevant to me (the ones I've asked, answered, or favorited) across various SE sites.  Recently I noticed that this script stopped downloading favorites.  And indeed, the URL https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users/17064/favorites?sort=activity&order=asc&site=mathoverflow&filter=bYJ_Djhc_U%29oHdva4ija%29v&min=1661983200 now returns an empty list.

I suppose this is due to bookmarks having been renamed to “saves”, but this doesn't tell me how to actually use this feature programmatically.  [The API documentation](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/favorites-on-users) says nothing about favorites being deprecated, nor does it provide a hint as to what the replacement method is or anything of the sort.

So, is there some way I can get something equivalent to the old behavior except by scraping the HTML from https://mathoverflow.net/users/saves/17064?sort=activity which is precisely what I wanted to avoid by using the API?

(Note that I'm fine with a solution that would involve, for example, re-migrating my “saves” to bookmarks if that's in any way possible.  I have no objection to them being publicly visible, for example.)

Comment: Part of the change is making it private, we can no longer see what other people Save.

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard Yes, I'm fine with either providing an access token or somehow making my saved list public. I don't care wither way. But my question is: is there an API method which will work?

Comment: This I don't know, but my educated guess is there isn't, they still didn't reach this stage, and removed it from the API due to Saves being private.

Comment: (BTW, this was already asked [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/382645/152859), without official response.)

Answer (score 15):

As part of the Saves launch, I failed to communicate anything about the API in the FAQ section of the [launch announcement post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382019/bookmarks-have-evolved-into-saves/), however we have tickets created to do some investigation of the current API usage and determine what steps we need to take to either support the existing features (i.e. saved questions but only for your account) and/or potentially creating a new set of APIs for Saves. Once we have a plan finalized, we will communicate back to Meta.

Comment: "Once we have a plan finalized" - something tells me it's going to take a very long time. :(

Comment: And of course I'm correct, sadly. One of those times I don't like being correct.