# Unable to fetch favorite/bookmarked questions

Tags: bug, bookmarks, api

I'm not able to fetch the favorite questions using the stack exchange api (https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/me-favorites).
This looks like a recent issue
because it was working fine a couple of months back.

Below is the screenshot of the result of fetching favorites from [stackexchange api](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/me-favorites)

[image: Screenshot of the result of fetching favorites from stackexchange api]

---

Related Questions/references:

- [API request for "favorites" now returning an empty list – is there a way to get something equivalent for saves?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/382991/381523)
- [Bookmarks have evolved into Saves](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/382645/381523)

Comment: Correct. Both Favorites and Bookmarks (which are the same) are no more, gone. Now there is something else called "Saves" which isn't public anymore.

Comment: BTW, off topic, but important, your website is down. Please edit to updated website or remove it from your profile.

Comment: Thank you pointing out the website issue. its fixed now

Comment: Found [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/382991/381523) which talks about this. Another post [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/382645/381523)

Comment: Nice fix, thanks. And yeah, looks like you missed the fact I've closed your question as duplicate of the question you found. (So you didn't really have to look hard to find it. ;))

Comment: Oh, I actually found it because you closed the question. I just added the links in the comment for quick reference. Thank you for the references 