# We should be able to change which saves list a question is in directly from the question page

Tags: feature-request, saves

Let's say there is a question in your saves, and you want to change which saves list it is in. As far as I can tell, the only way to do that is to go to the Saves tab on your profile (https://math.stackexchange.com/users/saves/177399 for me), scroll down until you find that question, click on the three-dots menu, and select the "Move to..." option. However, I have over 300 items in my saves list, so it is huge pain to find the one I am looking for. There is no way to search in the saves list. When you use the main search bar, the results do not come with a "Move to.." option.

The feature I am requesting is that you should be able to go to the question page itself, and change the save list it is in from there. Right now, you can only toggle whether or not a question is saved at all from the question page, by clicking on the ribbon icon.

One workaround is that you can go to the question page, click the ribbon twice to unsave and resave it. Now, the when you sort your saves in "Added" order, the question will be at the very top. I do not like this alternative, because it is unintuitive, and it forces you to change the order your questions were added in just to change a folder.

Comment: It is an obvious upgrade (and thus likely a duplicate). Here is [one on MSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/423851/default-list-for-question-saving#comment951706_423851). Our only hope is someone higher up inside the company [getting so irritated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eating_your_own_dog_food#Examples) that they demand it being implemented.

Comment: **Related:** https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/387120/see-private-notes-on-saved-posts

Answer (score 1):

> Right now, you can only toggle whether or not a question is saved at all from the question page, by clicking on the ribbon icon.

This is incorrect, you are able to change the list.

Once the Save icon is clicked, there is a notification that reads "Question saved to **For later**" which shows the list it goes to. The same notification has a "Manage" button on the right side

[image: The save notification with the manage button.]

Clicking on Manage allows changing the list a post goes to as well as the ability to create a new list:

[image: Dialog with a selection of list to save.]

Closing the dialog with the Done button will move the post to the selected list from the default one.

Comment: But reload and that banner with the link is gone. That is not a solution and not what the request is asking for.

Comment: @ShadowTheSpringWizard I pointed out the incorrect part of the statement which says that we can **only** toggle whether it's saved or not. The ability to change where a save is *when you load up the page with an already saved post* is:  1. a separate thing, not at all covered by what I've explained here. 2. My post isn't even meant to be a "solution" for this. Again, it's only informative. 3. I'm pretty sure there is a FR for this functionality because I'm pretty sure I've upvoted such a thing in the past. In summary: yes my post doesn't solve a problem it never tried to nor meant to solve.