# Possible to inadvertently delete a private note when "unsaving" a post from a Saves list

Tags: bug, saves, private-notes

After displaying a Saves list, it is possible to add a private note to a Saved post or "unsave" the post from the Saves list:

[image: adding a private note to a Saved post]

Both of these actions are fine and create no issues.

However, after adding a private note, the "unsave" action becomes a little unsafe because not only is the post "unsaved" from the Saves list, but the private note is also deleted. Naturally, the "Edit private note" and "Delete private note" actions are fine.

[image: editing or deleting a private note]

We can argue that "unsaving" a post here and simultaneously deleting a private note is not an issue because, after all, the user can see the private note under the post clearly on a yellowish background.

However, this is not the case from the post itself. Clicking on the Saves icon next to the voting buttons unsaves the post from its Saves list and deletes any private note attached to it without any warning. This is unsafe.

[image: unsaving a question]

New functionality to the Saves feature has already been proposed [in this feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/387120/1242908) and [this suggested improvement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/382625/1242908) which would probably make this problem less likely, however inadvertently deleting private notes is probably a more serious issue and could be considered to be a bug.

Comment: I think that adding a warning prior "unsaving" is rather a "feature-request" than a "bug".

Comment: @αλεχολυτ Yes, that is true. There must be many ways of fixing this and I am not making any suggestion here which way would be desirable or chosen, so I am not making a feature request, all I am doing is highlighting the silent deletion of data. I linked to the other two requests as the issues are most probably connected.