# Is there an RSS feed for a user's saves/favorites?

Tags: feature-request, bookmarks, feed, saves

I think this is a duplicate of [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25194/rss-feed-for-favorite-questions), but that was asked 13 years ago, and [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64987/1411202) from 300 weeks ago no longer works as far as I can tell (I get a 404 error when I try it).

As I understand it, [Saves was overhauled last year](https://stackoverflow.blog/2022/10/04/meet-saves-the-tool-to-help-you-organize-your-favorite-content-on-stack-overflow/) as well.

So is it possible to access the list of *Saves* via an RSS feed, or is this functionality gone?

To clarify, I'm specifically looking for an RSS feed, rather than scraping via the browser console or the API, unlike [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/391982/how-can-i-download-my-saves-lists).

Comment: saves are private, so if it existed, it would probably only be for your own stuff and require some sort of authentication. I've [feature-requested making saves lists publishable](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/391888/997587).