# Don't show the "New! We have saves now!" popup on every session, please

Tags: support, user-interface, saves

I use more than three devices and multiple browsers and am frequently not logged in and/or clear my cookies.

This means that multiple times a day, I'm greeted by this obnoxious popup:

> [image: I KNOW!]

Yes, I know, you renamed bookmarks to saves and are very proud of it. Now let me get to my content without distractions.

The ["Trending sort available" label](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/419526/suggestions-for-the-trending-sort-available-i-label) was equally obnoxious and annoyed me for weeks.

This one, the *"New! We renamed our bookmarks to saves!"* popup, must be gone, soon, please. Whether you dismissed the popup seems to be remembered in a cookie (when you're not logged in), or per account/site combo, or forgotten on logout, or a combination thereof.

I don't want to figure out how the popup works, I don't want to block the element in all my browsers on all my machines, I don't want to stay logged in, I just want this annoying as hell popup gone, please.

So: no, this is not about cookies. This is about choosing yet another very "in your face" way to announce new features, which gets in the way of actual content.

Comment: Alternatively: how long are you planning on running this popup, so I can plan my absence?

Comment: Your post contradicts announcement made by staff [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382019/bookmarks-have-evolved-into-saves#comment1277041_382879): "For now, the popover has been disabled on all sites except for Stack Overflow." You should only be seeing this on SO. You clearing your cookies or using incognito browsing is always likely to result in a degraded experience, that's a choice you've made.

Comment: @Luuk wow, that's weird, I could swear I saw it on other sites just today. My memory is off then. As for the "degraded experience", hard disagree, SO's way of announcing features is what's wrong, not my not so uncommon browsing behavior.

Comment: @Luuklag at least on this very site it's shown as well: https://i.stack.imgur.com/q7k5M.png

Comment: It might be worth replying to the comment I linked then @CodeCaster.

Comment: @Luuk no, I don't care about which sites should or shouldn't show this popup, I want annoying feature announcements/UI hacks to be gone altogether. There are dozens of ways of handling this, and SO seems to choose the most annoying ones every time. But alright, I've linked it there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As of today, the Saves popover has been disabled on Stack Overflow. Previously, we disabled it on every Stack Exchange site except for Stack Overflow. If you are still seeing it on a particular site, please let us know so we can investigate.

Answer (score 3):

You can definitely recreate the pop up at will by running in incognito mode. At least on mobile, I see it daily.

[image: example]

Comment: I'd rather _not_ recreate the experience unnecessarily, thanks a lot.

Comment: You beat me to posting about this, but my take was going to be related to making incognito annoying.