# How can I delete a saves list?

Tags: support, saves

I have some saves lists (in my Stack Overflow account) created by myself:

[image]

How do I delete them?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Three steps:

1. Click on the list you want to delete.
2. Click on the "Edit list" button to the right.
3. Click "Delete list" button in the dialog that opens up.

[image: three steps to delete a list]

P.S.

I happened to [ask already](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/382641/152859) to make this more simple.

Comment: @InanimateBeing not sure, so I really prefer to go on the safe side. There is a line between hints and actually telling people how to solve the puzzle, and your answer was going towards the later. Giving hint when asked something directly in comments might be fine, I even did it myself, but when it's listed and given in a spoon, that might cross the line mentioned before.