# How are the lists of saves ordered?

Tags: support, sorting, saves

When I am saving a question to a specific lists, how are is the list of my lists sorted? (To some extent I am asking out of curiosity - regardless of the ordering, the lists are usable just fine.)

For example, on this site I have more than one list among my saves. When I click on the "bookmark icon" and then on "Manage" - i.e., if I do not want to save it simply as "For Later" - I am offered a menu to choose a list. For example, when I just tried it, I got this:

[image: Screenshot]

What is actually the ordering of the lists in this menu?

- It is not alphabetical.
- This screenshot might suggest that they are ordered by the number of questions - but when I tried the same on some other sites, I saw that this isn't the case.
- It doesn't seem to be with the most recently added lists at the top - at least if the [added tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/saves/current?sort=Added) in my Saves shows correct ordering. But after some checking, maybe they are ordered in such way that the most recently used list is at the bottom?
- Robert Longson added in a comment a link to [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382019/bookmarks-have-evolved-into-saves/384084#384084) which suggests as another hypothesis that they are ordered by the id of the list. This would be consistent with my lists on this site, too.

Comment: See https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/384084/188189