# Display the number of times a question has been saved

Tags: feature-request, saves

Displaying the number of times a question had been starred/saved had some positive uses:

1. A high number of saves sometimes indicated a question was especially important or more complex than it seemed at first glance, hinting that the question and/or answers might best be more thoroughly read and examined (e.g. for gotchas or unintuitive results) than average.
2. Sometimes it provided an indication that others intended to spend more time thinking about the topic in the future. For a prospective answerer, that knowledge could encourage them to answer in cases where they otherwise may not have.

Please consider bringing it back.

Comment: I often bookmarked questions because they were bad, in order to remember to go back and vote to delete once they'd been closed so many saves/bookmarks does not necessarily mean what you think it does.

Comment: @RobertLongson that's true. A typical case might be a question with 10, or 20, or 50 saves. Number of saves in relation to the number of upvotes is often very useful too. For example if a question has 20 upvotes and as many saves, it could indicate strongly that there's something going on; some desire for further learning on that particular topic. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11784408/vim-multiline-editing-like-in-sublimetext) is a random example, it has score: 186, I'd be curious to know how many saves. I suspect >50, but I am not sure. >50 indicates *cont*

Comment: users are invested in really understanding how to understand/solve this particular problem, but <50 I'd tend to interpret as possibly me simply lacking an understanding of existing answers. It's purely a quick guide, and only to be used as a proxy and in conjunction with other info. I'd be surprised if most users paid attention to the metric, but for me it was sometimes insightful.

Comment: "A high number of saves sometimes indicated a question was especially important" Not necessarily. It's just one more useless metric that's easily misinterpreted. I'm glad we got rid of it.

Comment: @Mast except there is *still* badges for questions with a high number of saves.

Comment: @ElementsinSpace Next step would be to remove those too, but retiring badges is a controversial topic. I'd just leave it as-is for now.

Comment: @Mast sure, but presumably you'd use common sense interpreting it, be wary of such false-positives, and if it's still not useful, don't use it.

Comment: @Mast Also note use of the word "*sometimes*". The key idea being that something doesn't have to be useful in 100% of cases to be worth having. A good example, I guess, is an umbrella.

Comment: @Rob adding a useless addition is not a proper way to force your review action.

Comment: @Sha, the same could be said of your action. How does that address the issue?

Comment: @Rob it doesn't address any issue, IMO "starred/saved" is better grammar than "starred / saved" so I rolled back the edit I considered as wrong.

Answer (score 7):

Worth to mention it was [already requested](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/382640/152859), and kind of declined.

The [official response](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382019/bookmarks-have-evolved-into-saves/382637#comment1276702_382640) by SE staff says:

> the short answer to your question about whether this is intentional/by-design is yes. There are not current plans to bring this back with the Saves launch.

So while not outright rejecting the request, it means there are no plans to make it happen either.